# bash shell script for mac to generate word list from a file?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Is there a shell script that runs on a mac to generate a word list from a text file, listing the unique words? Even better if it could sort by frequency....

sorry forgot to mention, yeah i prefer a bash one as i'm using mac now...

oh, my file is in french... (basically i'm reading a novel and learning french, so i try to generate a word list help myself). hope this is not a problem?

Comment: what is the script you have tried

Comment: What environment? Windows? Linux/Mac/Unix?

Comment: @Matt This only sorts and makes Unique. It doesn't extract the words from a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will do

```
cat file.txt |  tr "\"' " '\n' | sort -u
```

Here `sort -u` will not work on Macintosh machines. In that case use `sort | uniq -c` instead. (Thanks to [Hank Gay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4203))

```
cat file.txt |  tr "\"' " '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: I think `sort | uniq -c` is a better option for finishing it off, because `sort -u` (on a Mac) will not show the words, just the counts.

Comment: it works! but need a few modification... 1. no word count 2. not writing directly to an output file 3. need replace not only ( ) but also ('), but thanks this is the way to go!

Comment: how could i replace the double and single quotes with new line?

Comment: thank you guys. i used a slight different way: tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < file.txt | sort | uniq -c

Comment: @HankGay: what version of Mac OS X? On my machine (OS 10.7.4), `/usr/bin/sort` is  from GNU coreutils 5.93, and `-u` produces words, not counts.

Comment: @chepner I'm on Snow Leopard at the moment, although my `sort` version appears to match yours. Very strange.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like that:

```
cat <filename> | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: You can probably dig into `sed`'s regex documentation to make the script a little more comprehensive, but that's how I'd do it, except you have to do hackery to actually get a newline, a la http://stackoverflow.com/a/7567839/4203

Comment: @athos See my comment. This is because you're on a Mac (I am, too), and I'm pretty sure Mac doesn't ship GNU `sed` (it's BSD-based).

Comment: @athos It's easy enough to work around. In fact, if you mix-and-match the two answers already posted (to use `tr` instead of `sed`), you get `$ cat $YOUR_FILE | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c`, and I think that gets you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just answer my question to dot down the final version i'm using:

```
tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "\n" < FileIn.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2","$1}' >> FileOut.csv
```

some notes:

- tr can be used directly to do replacement.
- since i'm interested creating a word list for my french vocabulary, i used [:alpha:]
- awk is used to insert a comma, so that the output is a csv file, easier for me to upload...

thanks again for everyone helping me.

sorry i didn't put it clearly at the beginning that i'm using a mac and expect a bash script.

cheers.