# How do I insert a newline/linebreak after a line using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, zsh

It took me a while to figure out how to do this, so posting in case anyone else is looking for the same.

Comment: [Insert blank line in UNIX after different number of lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222810/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 37):

For adding a newline after a pattern, you can also say:

```
sed '/pattern/{G;}' filename
```

Quoting [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands):

```
G
    Append a newline to the contents of the pattern space, and then append the contents of the hold space to that of the pattern space.
```

**EDIT:**

Incidentally, this happens to be covered in [sed one liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt):

```
 # insert a blank line below every line which matches "regex"
 sed '/regex/G'
```

Comment: `sed '/\n/G' filename` doesn't work. But `sed '/e/G' filename` works.

Answer (score 10):

This sed command:

```
sed -i '' '/pid = run/ a\
\
' file.txt
```

Finds the line with: pid = run

**file.txt before**

```
; Note: the default prefix is /usr/local/var
; Default Value: none
;pid = run/php-fpm.pid

; Error log file
```

and adds a linebreak after that line inside file.txt

**file.txt after**

```
; Note: the default prefix is /usr/local/var
; Default Value: none
;pid = run/php-fpm.pid


; Error log file
```

Or if you want to add text and a linebreak:

```
sed -i '/pid = run/ a\
new line of text\
' file.txt
```

**file.txt after**

```
; Note: the default prefix is /usr/local/var
; Default Value: none
;pid = run/php-fpm.pid
new line of text

; Error log file
```

Comment: `sed 'a'` is a pretty good idea ... I would've used `sed -e '/pid = run/ s/$/\n/'` or `sed -e '/pid = run/ s/$/\nnew line of text/'`

Answer (score 7):

A simple substitution works well:

```
sed 's/pattern.*$/&\n/'
```

Example :

```
$ printf "Hi\nBye\n" | sed 's/H.*$/&\nJohn/'
Hi
John
Bye
```

To be standard compliant, replace \n by backslash newline :

```
$ printf "Hi\nBye\n" | sed 's/H.*$/&\
> John/'
Hi
John
Bye
```

Comment: To answer the question as asked, you'd have to do `sed 's/pattern.*/&\n/'`, otherwise you'll insert the newline right after the match instead of at the end of the line. Also note that your solution requires _GNU_ `sed` (won't work on BSD/OSX, because the BSD `sed` implementation doesn't support escape sequence `\n` in the _replacement string_).

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't know about the difference between GNU sed and BSD/OSX sed. Worth knowing !

Comment: ++; there are many differences, unfortunately; BSD Sed implements only a few extensions to the POSIX spec., while GNU Sed implements many more  - I've tried to compile the differences in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375).

Comment: With GNU sed and ripgrep (rg) in a terminal this worked for me: `rg . --color always -in -e 'apples' |sort | sed 's|\./|======================\n|'` to separate rg results lines, where the raw results begin with `./10643.html:...`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/pattern/a\\r' file name
```

It will add a return after the pattern while `g` will replace the pattern with a blank line.

If a new line (blank) has to be added at end of the file use this:

```
sed '$a\\r' file name
```

Comment: CARRIAGE RETURN vs LINE FEED: some people will need to use a `\n` instead of a `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, e.g. if You don't have an empty hold register, could be:

```
sed '/pattern/{p;s/.*//}' file
```

Explanation:
    **`/pattern/{...}`** = apply sequence of commands, if line with pattern found,
    **`p`** = print the current line,
    **`;`** = separator between commands,
    **`s/.*//`** = replace anything with nothing in the pattern register,
    then automatically print the empty pattern register as additional line)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option -->

sed 'i\

' filename

Comment: every other answer interpret the question as 'inserting empty line after a **pattern matched line**'. This answer does not even pattern match.