# sed not giving me correct substitute operation for newline with Mac - differences between GNU sed and BSD / OSX sed

Tags: macos, sed, gnu, bsd

I'm using this reference : [sed help: matching and replacing a literal "\n" (not the newline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762365/sed-help-matching-and-replacing-a-literal-n-not-the-newline)

and I have a file "test1.txt" that contains a string hello\ngoodbye

I use this command to search and replace "\n" with actual new line characters:

```
sed -i '' 's/\\n/\n/g' test1.txt
```

but the result is: **hellongoodbye**.
it just replaces the "\n" with "n" and not an actual new line. This does the same with /t where it will leave a "t" and not a tab.

the '' is for the undefined error in MAC: http://mpdaugherty.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/difference-with-sed-in-place-editing-on-mac-os-x-vs-linux/

**Update**:

I've tried both of the commands that @hek2mgl suggested:

```
sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' test.txt
# Or:
sed -i'' 's/\\n/\n/g' test.txt
```

While they might work with Linux, with MAC OS I got the following error:

```
sed: 1: "test1.txt": undefined label 'est1.txt'
```

Not sure why I can't get this to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the same thing in Linux (currently in Ubuntu), and it works for me with `sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' input.txt`.

Comment: The error message means that it's interpreting the string `test1.txt` as the sed script, where `t` is the command, a conditional branch to the label called `ext1.txt`, which of course doesn't exist. It's strange that the empty argument is necessary, but I think it's a red-herring relative to the problem with the newline.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**With BSD/macOS `sed`, to use a newline in the *replacement string* of an `s` function call, you must use an `\`-escaped *actual* newline**  - escape sequence `\n` is *not* supported there (unlike in the *regex* part of the call).

- *Either*: simply insert an *actual* newline:

  ```
  sed -i '' 's/\\n/\
  /g' test1.txt
  ```
- *Or*: use an [ANSI C-quoted string (`$'...'`)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to splice in the newline (`$'\n'`; works in `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`):

  ```
  sed -i '' 's/\\n/\'$'\n''/g' test1.txt
  ```

*GNU* `sed`, by contrast, *does* recognize `\n` in replacement strings; read on for a comprehensive overview of the differences between these two implementations.

---

#### Differences between GNU `sed` (Linux) and BSD/macOS `sed`

*macOS* uses the *BSD* version of `sed`<sup>[1]</sup>, which differs in many respects from the *GNU* `sed` version that comes with *Linux* distros.

Their **common denominator** is the functionality decreed by **POSIX**: see [the POSIX `sed` spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

The **most portable approach** is to **use POSIX features only**, which, however, **limits functionality**:

- Notably, POSIX specifies **support only for *basic* regular expressions**, which have many limitations (e.g., no support for `|` (alternation) at all, no direct support for `+` and `?`) and different escaping requirements.

  - Caveat: **GNU `sed` (without `-r`), *does* support `\|`, `\+` and `\?`, which is NOT POSIX-compliant; use `--posix` to disable** (see below).
- **To use POSIX features only**:

  - (both versions): use *only* the `-n` and `-e` options (notably, do *not* use `-E` or `-r` to turn on support for *extended* regular  expressions)
  - GNU `sed`: add option `--posix` to ensure POSIX-only functionality (you don't strictly need this, but without it you could end up inadvertently using non-POSIX features without noticing; *caveat*: `--posix` *itself* is *not* POSIX-compliant)
  - Using POSIX-only features means stricter formatting requirements (forgoing many conveniences available in GNU `sed`):

    - Control-character sequences such as `\n` and `\t` are generally NOT supported.
    - Labels and branching commands (e.g., `b`) *must* be followed by an *actual* newline or continuation via a separate `-e` option.
    - See below for details.

**However, *both* versions implement *extensions* to the POSIX standard:**

- ***what* extensions they implement differs** (GNU `sed` implements more).
- even those **extensions they *both* implement *partially differ in syntax***.

**If you need to support BOTH platforms (discussion of differences):**

- **Incompatible** features:

  - Use of the **`-i` option *without* an argument** (in-place updating without backup) is incompatible:

    - BSD `sed`: MUST use `-i ''`
    - GNU `sed`: MUST use just `-i` (equivalent: `-i''`) - using `-i ''` does NOT work.
  - **`-i` sensibly turns on *per-input-file* line numbering** in *GNU* `sed` and *recent* versions of *BSD* `sed` (e.g., on FreeBSD 10), but does **NOT on macOS as of 10.15**.
    Note that in the absence of `-i` *all* versions number lines *cumulatively* across input files.
  - If the ***last* input line does *not* have a trailing newline** (and is printed):

    - BSD `sed`: *always appends a newline* on output, even if the input line doesn't end in one.
    - GNU `sed`: *preserves the trailing-newline status*, i.e., it appends a newline only if the input line ended in one.

- **Common** features:

  - If you restrict your `sed` scripts to what BSD `sed` supports, they will generally work in GNU `sed` too - with the notable exception of using platform-specific *extended* regex features with `-E`. Obviously, you'll also forgo extensions that are specific to the GNU version. See next section.

---

**Guidelines for *cross-platform support* (macOS/BSD, Linux), driven by the stricter requirements of the BSD version**:

<sup>Note that I'm using the shorthands *macOS* and *Linux* for the BSD and GNU versions of `sed` respectively because they are the stock versions on each platform. However, it is possible to install GNU `sed` on macOS, for instance, using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install gnu-sed`.</sup>

**Note**: ***Except for when the `-r` and `-E` flags are used*** (*extended* regexes), the instructions below amount to writing **POSIX-compliant** `sed` scripts.

- For POSIX compliance, you must restrict yourself to [POSIX BREs (*basic* regular expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which are, unfortunately, as the name suggests, quite basic.
  **Caveat**: do not assume that `\|`, `\+` and `\?` are supported: While GNU `sed` supports them (unless `--posix` is used), BSD `sed` does not - these features are *not* POSIX-compliant.
  While **`\+` and `\?` *can* be emulated** in POSIX-compliant fashion :
  `\{1,\}` for `\+`,
  `\{0,1\}` for `\?`,
  **`\|` (alternation) *cannot***, unfortunately.
- For more powerful regular expressions, **use `-E`** (rather than `-r`) to support **EREs (*extended* regular expressions)** (GNU `sed` doesn't document `-E`, but it does work there as an alias of `-r`; *newer* version of BSD `sed`, such as on FreeBSD 10, now also support `-r`, but the macOS version as of 10.10 does *not*).
  **Caveat**: Even though use of `-r` / `-E` means that your command is by definition *not* POSIX-compliant, you must still **restrict yourself to [POSIX EREs (extended regular expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)**. Sadly, this means that you won't be able to use several useful constructs, notably:

  - word-boundary assertions, because they're *platform-specific* (e.g., `\<` on Linux, `[[:<]]` on OS X).
  - back-references *inside regular expressions* (as opposed to the "back-references" to capture-group matches in the replacement string of `s` function calls), because BSD `sed` doesn't support them in *extended* regexes (but, curiously, does so in *basic* ones, where they are POSIX-mandated).
- **Control-character escape sequences such as `\n` and `\t`:**

  - In **regexes** (both in patterns for selection and the first argument to the `s` function), assume that only `\n` is recognized as an escape sequence (rarely used, since the pattern space is usually a *single* line (without terminating `\n`), but not inside a *character class*, so that, e.g., `[^\n]` doesn't work; (if your input contains no control chars. other than `\t`, you can emulate `[^\n]` with `[[:print:][:blank:]]`; otherwise, splice control chars. in as *literals*<sup>[2]</sup>)  - **generally, include control characters as *literals*, either via spliced-in *ANSI C-quoted strings* (e.g., `$'\t'`) in shells that support it (`bash,`ksh, `zsh`), or via *command substitutions using `printf`* (e.g., `"$(printf '\t')"`)**.

    - Linux only:
      `sed 's/\t/-/' <<<$'a\tb' # -> 'a-b'`
    - macOS *and* Linux:
      `sed 's/'$'\t''/-/' <<<$'a\tb'            # ANSI C-quoted string`
      `sed 's/'"$(printf '\t')"'/-/' <<<$'a\tb' # command subst. with printf`
  - In **replacement strings** used with the `s` command, **assume that NO control-character escape sequences are supported**, so, again, include control chars. as *literals*, as above.

    - Linux only:
      `sed 's/-/\t/' <<<$'a-b' # -> 'a<tab>b'`
      `sed 's/-/\n/' <<<$'a-b' # -> 'a<newline>b'`
    - macOS *and* Linux:
      `sed 's/-/'$'\t''/' <<<'a-b'`
      `sed 's/-/'"$(printf '\t')"'/' <<<'a-b'`
      `sed 's/-/\'$'\n''/' <<<'a-b'`
      Note that newlines need to be backslash-escaped so that they are properly interpreted as part of the replacement string and not as the end of the command, and that using `printf` does not work for newlines since trailing newlines are removed by command substitutions (`$(...)`).
  - Ditto for the **text arguments** to the **`i` and `a` functions**: **do not use control-character sequences** - see below.
- **Labels and branching**: labels as well as the label-name *argument* to the `b` and `t` functions **must be followed by either by a *literal* newline or a spliced-in `$'\n'`**. Alternatively, use multiple `-e` options and terminate each right after the label name.

  - Linux only:
    `sed -n '/a/ bLBL; d; :LBL p' <<<$'a\nb' # -> 'a'`
  - macOS *and* Linux:

    - EITHER (actual newlines):
      `sed -n '/a/ bLBL
      d; :LBL
      p' <<<$'a\nb'`
    - OR (spliced-in `$\n` instances):
      `sed -n '/a/ bLBL'$'\n''d; :LBL'$'\n''p' <<<$'a\nb'`
    - OR (multiple `-e` options):
      `sed -n -e '/a/ bLBL' -e 'd; :LBL' -e 'p' <<<$'a\nb'`
- Functions **`i` and `a` for inserting/appending text**: **follow the function name by `\`, followed either by a *literal* newline or a spliced-in `$'\n'`** before specifying the text argument.

  - Linux only:
    `sed '1 i new first line' <<<$'a\nb' # -> 'new first line<nl>a<nl>b'`
  - macOS *and* Linux:
    `sed -e '1 i\'$'\n''new first line' <<<$'a\nb'`
  - Note:

    - Without `-e`, the text argument is inexplicably not newline-terminated on output in macOS (bug?).
    - **Do not use control-character escapes** such as `\n` and `\t` in the text argument, as they're only supported on Linux.
    - If the text argument therefore has actual interior newlines, `\`-escape them.
    - If you want to place additional commands after the text argument, you must terminate it with an (unescaped) newline (whether literal or spliced in), or continue with a separate `-e` option (this is a general requirement that applies to all versions).
- Inside **function *lists*** (multiple function calls enclosed in `{...}`), **be sure to also terminate the *last* function, before the closing `}`, with `;`**.

  - Linux only:
  - `sed -n '1 {p;q}' <<<$'a\nb' # -> 'a'`
  - macOS *and* Linux:
  - `sed -n '1 {p;q;}' <<<$'a\nb'`
- With the **`-f` option** (to read commands from a file), only GNU `sed` supports `-` as a placeholder for stdin; **use `-f /dev/stdin` to portably read commands from stdin**, including from here-documents (assuming your platform supports `/dev/stdin`, which is typically the case nowadays).

---

**GNU `sed`-specific features** missing from BSD `sed` altogether:

GNU features you'll miss out on if you need to support both platforms:

- Various **regex-matching and substitution options** (both in patterns for line selection and the first argument to the `s` function):

  - **The `I` option for case-INsensitive regex matching (incredibly, BSD `sed` doesn't support this at all).**
  - The `M` option for multi-line matching (where `^` / `$` match the start / end of *each line*)
  - For additional options that are specific to the `s` function see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command
- **Escape sequences**

  - Substitution-related escape sequences such as `\u` in the replacement argument of the `s///` function that allow *substring manipulation*, within limits; e.g., `sed 's/^./\u&/' <<<'dog' # -> 'Dog'` - see http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command
  - Control-character escape sequences: in addition to `\n`, `\t`, ..., codepoint-based escapes; for instance, all of the following escapes (hex., octal, decimal) represent a single quote (`'`): `\x27`, `\o047`, `\d039` - see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes
- **Address extensions**, such as `first~step` to match every step-th line, `addr, +N` to match N lines following `addr`, ... - see http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses

---

<sup>[1] The macOS `sed` version is *older* than the version on other BSD-like systems such as FreeBSD and PC-BSD. Unfortunately, this means that you cannot assume that features that work in FreeBSD, for instance, will work [the same] on macOS.</sup>

<sup>[2] The ANSI C-quoted string `$'\001\002\003\004\005\006\007\010\011\013\014\015\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037\177'` contains all ASCII control characters except `\n` (and NUL), so you can use it in combination with `[:print:]` for a pretty robust emulation of `[^\n]`:

`'[[:print:]'$'\001\002\003\004\005\006\007\010\011\013\014\015\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037\177'']`</sup>

Answer (score 6):

This might seem a little odd, but try:

```
sed -i '' 's/\\n/\
/g' test1.txt
```

I.e., use an *actual* newline instead of `\n`.

The explanation is that you have a weird `sed`!
For details, see the mac sed manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

In the description of the `s` command there, it says:

```
A line can be split by substituting a newline character into it.  To specify
a newline character in the replacement string, precede it with a backslash.
```

Also, in the description of the `-i` option, it says that the extension is not optional, and that if you don't want one you must specify an empty argument. So everything makes sense in the end!

Comment: I get this error: "sed: 1: "s/\\n/
/g": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern"

Comment: I've edited it. Try it again (with the backslash before the newline).

Comment: This worked! :D, can you explain please in your answer? and possibly why it's not working as intended with MAC as opposed to linux?