# running into error with multiline sed statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a very long sed statement that is 6 lines long strung together with -e. I am doing multiple replacements and writing to the same file.

It throws me an error for any sed statement over one line. How can I rectify this?

Some have suggested using variables to reduce the text length, but even still I think that solution won't work for me. Is there another simpler way to make this work?

Thanks.

edit: 
I just wasn't using my line breaks properly.
Working script:

```
sed -e 's/horse.*/300/g' \
-e 's/goat.*/320/g' \
-e 's/dog.*/310/g' \ 
-e 's/wolf.*/330/g' < "$file1" > "$file2"
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't you think it would be awesome if we could see your sed statement?

Comment: If you use multiple `-e` options, be sure to put a `\ ` (line continuation char.) at the end of all lines but the last.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Give an example.

Comment: Put your `\ ` at end of previous lines. (E.g.: `sed -e 's/horse.*/300/g' \<line-break>   -e 's/goat.*/320/g'` instead of `sed -e 's/horse.*/300/g' <line-break>\   -e 's/goat.*/320/g'`). `\ `s are meant to escape the (non-printed) `\n` end-of-line characters.

Comment: @Qeole Thanks. When I tried that I recieved the error: syntax error near unexpected token 'new line'. This happened on the line that holds the first line break.

Comment: I had not noticed that you're trying to give your expressions as distinct arguments to `sed`. Not sure it's possible. But you can pass multiple substitutions in a same `sed` expression, e.g.: `sed -e 's/horse.*/300/g ; s/goat.*/320/g'` (note that in this example you could replace `;` by `\<line-break>`).

Comment: @Qeole: Yes, it is possible to pass the overall `sed` script with _multiple_ `-e` options - that's even a POSIX feature - see http://man.cx/sed

Comment: Do not write `<linebreak>`! That was just to tell you to break line, as I can't do it in comments. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/horse.*/300/g' \  #replacing horse with horse300
-e 's/goat.*/320/g' \       #replacing goat with goat320   
-e 's/dog.*/310/g' \        #replacing dog with dog310
-e 's/wolf.*/330/g' < "$file1" > "$file2" #replacing wolf with wolf330 ; reading from file1, writing to file2
```

Above is the working code used for making multiple replacements using the same sed statement. Thanks again for all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
sed 's/horse.*/300/g;s/goat.*/320/g;s/dog.*/310/g;s/wolf.*/330/g' filename.txt
```

Your script never ends because you are not feeding your SED command with a filename.

Comment: Thanks. I am feeding a file, I just forgot to write it in the example. I apologize for my incompetence. With that being said, the code you posted will work if I try it, but my actual code will not fit on one line like that. My sed statement is much longer than this example. Thanks again.

Comment: @OldMopMan Just replace `;`s by `\ ` and line breaks.

Comment: @Qeole I think that's what I have. I have line breaks at the end of each line. I have edited the code in my original post to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: @Qeole: If the entire script is a _single_ string, Do NOT put `\ ` at the end of lines - just use line breaks - sed recognizes normal line breaks as command separators; in other words: just replace `;` with line breaks.

Comment: @mklement0 You're right (again!). I think I had in mind the example of OP and got confused.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused now. In my example, what do I want at the end of every line? I don't want \<linebreak> ?

Comment: @OldMopMan: You want `\ ` (note: due to formatting, it appears that there's a space after '\' - ignore that) at the _very end of every line_ (not even spaces after) _but the last_, with nothing after (except the _actual_ line break) - see my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @mklement0 Oh man, that's one of the first things I had tried. I must have typed it in wrong initially, but it works now. Thanks so much

Comment: @Qeole ,@mklement0 Thanks for hanging in there with me. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: OK, in that case, you can play with eval command and put everything (within ", " double quotes) in sed "..." < f1 > f2 reading from a file in the format that I mentioned above and then it wont be an ugly/long command, right! cheers

Comment: @OldMopMan: My pleasure; glad it's resolved. For the benefit of future readers: can you please create an answer yourself and put the resolution in there, then accept it (which you won't be able to do until 48 hours later)?

Comment: @ArunSangal: `eval` is rarely a good idea, but putting just the _script_ in a file is good alternative; you can load a script from a file with `sed -f`.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, I can do that. I had edited my original post with the correct code, but will create a new answer as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the **various options for passing a script (program) [made up of multiple commands] to `sed`**:

Let's assume you want to perform the following 2 commands:

- `s/a/A/`
- `s/b/B/`

on input `'ab'`, so as to get `'AB'`.

---

Use a **single-line string** and **separate the commands with `;`**:

```
echo 'ab' | sed 's/a/A/; s/b/B/'
```

**Caveat**: Some `sed` implementations - notably, FreeBSD/macOS `sed` require actual line breaks as part of *certain* commands, such as for defining labels and branching to them; typically, using separate `-e` options (see below) is an alternative.

<sup>For a comprehensive summary of the differences between GNU and FreeBSD/macOS `sed`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375).</sup>

---

Use a **multi-line string** and use **actual line breaks** to separate the commands:

```
echo 'ab' | sed -e '
              s/a/A/
              s/b/B/
              '
```

Note: You can also use a here-document with the `-f` option - see below.

---

Use **multiple `-e` options** to pass the commands **individually**.

```
echo 'ab' | sed -e 's/a/A/' -e 's/b/B/'
```

If your option arguments are long and you want to **spread the `-e` options across several lines, terminate *all but the last* line of the overall command with `\`** so as to signal to the *shell* that the command continues on the next line - note that the **`\` must be the very last character on the line** (not even spaces or tabs are allowed after it):

```
echo 'ab' | sed -e 's/a/A/' \
                -e 's/b/B/'
```

Note that this is a *general* requirement of the *shell* and has nothing to do with `sed` itself.

---

**Write your `sed` script to a *file* or use a *here-document***, and pass it to `sed` with the **`-f` option**:

```
# Create script file.
cat > myScript <<'EOF'
  s/a/A/
  s/b/B/
EOF

# Pass to `sed` with `-f`:
echo 'ab' | sed -f myScript

# Alternative, with a here-document via stdin, which requires
# the input to come from an actual file:
# Note: GNU sed also accepts `-f -`, but macOS sed does not.
echo 'ab' > test.txt
sed -f /dev/stdin test.txt <<'EOF'
  s/a/A/
  s/b/B/
EOF
```

---

Note:

- All POSIX-compatible `sed` implementations should support all these methods.
- You can even mix the `-f` and `-e` approaches, where the `-e` supplied command are *appended* to the overall script; e.g.: `echo 'abc' | sed  -f myScript -e 's/c/C/' # -> 'ABC'`
- If you use the variant with the [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) as the script (`<<'EOF'...`), use `-f /dev/stdin` to be portable (only *GNU* `sed` supports `-f -`).