# Editing few lines of a file in bash

Tags: regex, macos, sed

Hello I would like to parse a js file in bash containing settings in this way :

```
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

- if the lines do not exist, it should be created (>>append).
- if the lines are already set with those values : do nothing.
- If the lines are already set with different values, change it for values **"127.0.0.1"**, **9150**, **1**

So far I can perform point 1 and 2, but I struggle on point 3.
I believe it can be achieved by using bash conditionals, and '**sed**' with a regex pattern.
**Can anyone (regex guru) help me please ?**

---

Quick introduction to my problem :

I am writing a bash script on OS X and have socks5 listening on 127.0.0.1:9150.
I want then to set those settings for Firefox by editing the **prefs.js** file (equivalent of url **about:config**). The GUI for this is *Preferences/Advanced/Network/Connection Settings/Manual Proxy/Socks5*.

FYI, here's my script, the missing part is **###MISSING PART###** :

```
function sshD
{
    pkill firefox #Kill existing instance(s) of Firefox
    #Create HTTP Proxy via SSH Tunnel
    ssh -Cc blowfish -D9150 -Nf myuser@mydomain
    fxpref="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/"; fxpref="$fxpref`ls "$fxpref" | awk 'NR==1'`/prefs.js"
    test ! -f "$fxpref".backup && cp "$fxpref" "$fxpref".backup
    proxypref=`cat "$fxpref" | grep proxy`
    ###MISSING PART###
    /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -private > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

Comment: why can't you over write with the default values always with out performing any check?

Comment: Because this is point 3, I do not .know how to detect the line and replace it with sed. If I >>append, I end up creating duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that works with FreeBSD `sed` (OS X) as well as with GNU `sed` (Linux) - basics of the approach are based on [@anishsane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24508972/45375):

Note:

- The assumption is that it's OK to *not* preserve the original order of preferences in the input file so as to simplify the solution.
- Thus, this solution effectively *first* removes existing preferences of interest (if any) from the input file, and then *appends* them with the desired (new) values to the *end*.

```sh
sed -En '/user_pref\("network\.proxy\.(socks|socks_port|type)"/!p
        $ a\
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");\
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);\
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
        ' prefs.js
```

Note: The above just outputs the result to stdout; if you wanted to *replace* the input file with the result, saving the original to `*.backup`, use:

```
sed -En -i'.backup' ...
```

Explanation:

- `-E` turns on support for *extended* regular expressions, which adds crucial features such as `|` for alternation (aside from needing less escaping).
- `-n` suppresses default output of (potentially modified) input lines, so that only explicit output functions such as `p`, `a`, and `i` produce output.
- `/user_pref\("network\.proxy\.(socks|socks_port|type)"/!p` causes all lines NOT containing the preferences of interest to be printed; in other words: existing lines containing the preferences of interest (with their current values) are effectively *deleted*.
- `$ a` appends text to the output after the *last* line (`$`) of input, and here simply outputs the preferences of interest with the desired *new* values.
- Overall, the `\`-escaped newlines are carefully placed to make FreeBSD `sed` happy - a pure GNU `sed` solution would be simpler; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375 for the differences between the two implementations.

Comment: It is now working as expected thank you very much.Very good to know how to use sed on BSD, thank you again !

Comment: @FlorianBidabe: My pleasure; I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that firefox's pref.js is read line-by-line & the sequence of these preferences is not important.

So, this should work:

```
sed '/user_pref("network.proxy.\(socks\|socks_port\|type\)"/d;
        $auser_pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");\nuser_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);\nuser_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);' pref.js
```

Comment: Thank you anishsane, however the option -r does not exists on "Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0" (OS X 10.9).   man sed -> HISTORY : A sed command, written by L. E. McMahon, appeared in Version 7 AT&T UNIX. BSD May 10, 2005

Comment: I had added `-r` only to bypass some escaping of `(`, `|` with `\`... Misusing features for own laziness ;) Updated the answer.

Comment: On OSX you can use `-E` instead of `-r` (to enable support for _extended_ regexes)  (note that `-E` even works with GNU `sed`, though the manual doesn't say so). However: Alternation (`|`) in a _basic_ regex is not part of POSIX, so FreeBSD `sed` only supports alternation with `-E`. There are other things FreeBSD/OSX `sed` doesn't support, such as appending text directly to the `a` function and using `\n` in the text argument - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375

Comment: Thanks I did indeed have a "error: parentheses not balanced", but I now get a "sed: 1: "/user_pref("network.pro ...": command a expects \ followed by text". I'm sorry if I'n missing something essential.

Comment: FreeBSD/OSX ... OpenBSD/OSX(e.g. pfctl)... Linux...I thought using bash would kind of work both ways for unix/linux kernels/flavours, guess I'm not a developer fella.

Comment: ^^ `bash` & `sed` are independent :-)

Comment: `bash` is not in the mix here - only the differing `sed` implementations - there are, sadly, many small differences, which I've attempted to summarize in the linked answer. @FlorianBidabe: The short of it: follow `a` with `\ ` (ignore the space after - needed it for formatting) followed by an _actual_ newline; similarly, replace the `\n` instances with `\ ` followed by an _actual_ newline. (Alternatively, splice `$'\n'` into the string to create newlines).

Comment: Elegant solution - if you fix it to work on OSX, I'll up-vote.

Comment: Right, thanks for your help, I get that the shell(command line interpreter) has nothing to do with a unix utility like sed. You guys are more knowledgeable than I in terms of scripting, if we avoid using sed, since there are different implementations, Can we use something else ? I know vim but this requires manual input, right ?

Comment: <<Elegant solution - if you fix it to work on OSX, I'll up-vote.>> Guess I'm gonna spend an over sleepless night on this ahah

Comment: On 2nd thought: even with GNU `sed` your answer will only work if the last input line does not match the regex, because the `d` will otherwise prevent the `$a` from getting executed.

Comment: ^^ That's actually right. Even heuristically, the second time when the script runs, these entries will be at the end. But looks like your answer already has that covered.