# How can I cleanly output current mysql variables to a my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, regex, sed

I'm trying to run the following command to generate a `my.cnf`:

```sh
{
  # Print version, user, host and time
  echo -e "# MYSQL VARIABLES {{{1\n##\n# MYSQL `
      mysql -V | sed 's,^.*\(V.*\)\, for.*,\1,'
      ` - By: `logname`@`hostname -f` on `date +%c`\n##"
  for l in {a..z}; do
      # Get mysql global variables starting with $l
      echo '#'; mysql -NBe "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '${l}%'" |
      # Transorm it
      sed 's,\t,^= ,' |
      column -ts^ |
      tr "\n" '@' |
      eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\("{a..u}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'") |
      eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\(innodb_"{a..z}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'") |
      tr '@' "\n" |
      sed 's,^,# ,g'
  done
  echo -e "#\n##\n# MYSQL VARIABLES }}}1";
} | tee ~/mysql-variables.log
```

(original source for command: http://www.askapache.com/mysql/view-mysql-variables-my-cnf.html )

However `sed` keeps throwing an `unterminated substitute pattern` error:

```
sed: 3: " s,@\(aa\),\n\n\1,; s,@ ...": unterminated substitute pattern
sed: 2: " s,@\(innodb_aa\),\n\n\ ...": unterminated substitute pattern
#
sed: 3: " s,@\(aa\),\n\n\1,; s,@ ...": unterminated substitute pattern
sed: 2: " s,@\(innodb_aa\),\n\n\ ...": unterminated substitute pattern
#
```

How can I cleanly output my current mysql variables?

Comment: Since the issue seems to be with the regex only, I would extract just this part of your command if I were you. Your command line is not human readable, I am afraid. Divide and conquer.

Comment: The whole command works for me. Did you just run it from terminal, or launch it from something else (I'm thinking to something which could interpret quotes or `\n` before bash handles them)? Also, does `mysql -NBe "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES"` work as expected?

Comment: Thanks Evan for making it readable!

Comment: -_-" Well, if you look at post revisions history you'll see Evan hasn't done much on this one. I'll take those thanks for me if you don't mind :)

Comment: Ha. Thanks @Qeole!. And yes, I'm running it directly in terminal. And yes, `mysql -NBe "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES"` works as expected. Any idea how to handle the nested quotes better?

Comment: I get the same error either way (with or without the brackets).

Comment: I'm sorry I can't reproduce your `sed` error :/ Oh just to be sure, you're using bash, aren't you?

Comment: I ran the original single line without {} brackets and received: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know :/

Comment: Posted a new question to focus on nested quotes within the sed regex here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853398/how-can-i-reorganize-nested-quotes-within-sed-regex-in-a-bash-script-that-trigge Will report back here if I find anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in **this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854787/3716552)**, FreeBSD `sed` seems to have a limit on the size of individual lines in a script, which is exceeded by the `{a..u}{a..z}` bash expansion.

Here is a **`sed` script** that should have exactly the **same effect** as the combined two `eval …` lines (and their surrounding `tr` commands):

```bash
sed 'N;P;s/^innodb_//;tl;/.*\ninnodb_/{x;p;x;D};:l /^\(.\)\(.\).*\n\(innodb_\)\?\1\2/D;{x;p;x;D}' | …
```

---

**Edit:**
Corrected version by mklement0, using *FreeBSD `sed` syntax* (see comment below):

```bash
sed 'N;P;s/^innodb_//;tl'$'\n''/.*\ninnodb_/{x;p;x;D;};:l'$'\n''/^\(.\)\(.\).*\n\(in‌​nodb_\)\?\1\2/D;{x;p;x;D;}' | …
# Changes:              ^^^^^^^                     ^    ^^^^^^^                                            ^
```

---

*(Should replace all of this:)*

```bash
  tr "\n" '@' |
  eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\("{a..u}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'") |
  eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\(innodb_"{a..z}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'") |
  tr '@' "\n" |
```

**Now with details:** what we want to obtain with those two lines are kind of ***stanzas***, the first one containing all lines starting with `aa`, the second one lines starting with `ab`, etc.

**Bash expansion** in OP's script should result in something like

```bash
sed ' s,@\(aa\),\n\n\1,;
      s,@\(ab\),\n\n\1,;
      ...
      s,@\(uz\),\n\n\1,;' | # without line breaks
```

which would then be **evaluated**. To get **stanzas** we have to exectute each subcommand **exactly once** (and in this order, as input is sorted alphabetically), so using

```bash
sed 's/@\([a-u][a-z]\)/\n\n\1/' | ...
```

instead is **not** a solution.

**Back to my script:**

```bash
sed 'N;                              # Append next input line to pattern space
                                     # Pattern space is "input1 \n input2"

     P;                              # Print first line of pattern space

     s/^innodb_//;                   # Delete (already printed) suffix if present

         tl;                         # If substitution succeeded goto label l

         /.*\ninnodb_/{x;p;x;D};     # Else: if we\'re on first ^innodb_ line,
                                     # then print a new line before (see below)

  :l /^\(.\)\(.\).*\n\(innodb_\)\?\1\2/D;   # If the two lines in pattern space
                                     # begins with the same two chars, remove 1st
                                     # line and go on with next input line

     x;                              # We have to print a blank line: swap space
                                     # and hold patterns

     p;                              # Print space pattern (now empty), i.e.
                                     # print a new line

     x;                              # Swap again patterns

     D                               # Delete "input1 \n" from space pattern and
                                     # loop 
  ' | ...
```

Unless I'm mistaken, it should contain no GNU extension.

Comment: +1 (a little mind-bending, though, as is typical of line-spanning `sed` solutions), but note that while you're not using GNU sed _extensions_, you're using GNU sed _syntax_ - _FreeBSD/OSX sed has stricter syntax requirements_. You'd have to use the somewhat cumbersome `sed 'N;P;s/^innodb_//;tl'$'\n''/.*\ninnodb_/{x;p;x;D;};:l'$'\n''/^\(.\)\(.\).*\n\(innodb_\)\?\1\2/D;{x;p;x;D;}'` - the spliced-in newlines are crucial, as are the `;` instances before `}`. For a summary of differences between GNU sed and FreeBSD sed, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0. I wasn't aware of syntax differences between `sed` versions, it's good to know. I'm gonna read the post you link.

Comment: Thanks @Qeole, your extensive write up gets me right up to the finish line. The only thing left is adding the = sign between variables and associated values. I added another escape to handle the error where t's were replaced (`\\t`), but I still can't get the `=` to show up. Can you help me get all the way through this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ryan in your `sed 's,\t,^= ,' |` command, try replacing `\t` by either 1) a litteral tabulation character (just press `Tab`, so that it looks like this: `sed 's, ,^= ,' |`, or 2) an ANSI C-quoted string `$'\t'` (this way: `sed 's,'$'\t'',^= ,' |`). If you haven't already, you should have a look at post linked by mklement0, it's very interesting.