# How can I reorganize nested quotes within sed regex in a bash script that triggers an "unterminated substitute pattern" error?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, terminal

The following command is throwing an `unterminated substitute pattern` error in bash:

```
eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\("{a..u}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'")
```

But not for everyone. Linux apparently works fine. Mac throws the unterminated substitute pattern error.

How can I reorganize to make this work?

Here's the entire bash command (the goal is to cleanly output current MySQL settings into my.cnf) :

```
{
  # Print version, user, host and time
  echo -e "# MYSQL VARIABLES {{{1\n##\n# MYSQL `
      mysql -V | sed 's,^.*\(V.*\)\, for.*,\1,'
      ` - By: `logname`@`hostname -f` on `date +%c`\n##"
  for l in {a..z}; do
      # Get mysql global variables starting with $l
      echo '#'; mysql -NBe "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '${l}%'" |
      # Transorm it
      sed 's,\t,^= ,' |
      column -ts^ |
      tr "\n" '@' |
      eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\("{a..u}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'") |
      eval $(echo "sed '" "s,@\(innodb_"{a..z}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,;" "'") |
      tr '@' "\n" |
      sed 's,^,# ,g'
  done
  echo -e "#\n##\n# MYSQL VARIABLES }}}1";
} | tee ~/mysql-variables.log
```

Comment: The original answer I provided was valid. The new issue you have with cutting off the output is completely separate, related to `sed 's,\t,^= ,'`

Comment: Why are you using `eval` here at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `sed` in OS X is an BSD version of sed. Just tested:

- the above fails in OS X's default sed,
- and works with the GNU version (gsed - installed from macports).

So, probably the BSD version doesn't handles such long substitution command series.

You can try use the next:

```
eval $(echo "perl -ple '" "s,@("{a..u}{a..z}"),\n\n\1,;" "'")
```

And maybe I didn't understand right your goal, but what is a wrong with a much simpler?

```
sed 's/@\([a-u][a-z]\)/\n\n\1/' #or
sed 's/@\("[a-u][a-z]"\)/\n\n\1/'
```

### EDIT

Once again i'm only focused to the 1st code-line and not the whole solution. So created a bash/perl version what works without problems on OS X (with default OS X tools).

The next code

```
MYSQLCMD=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql   #your path to mysql command

printf "# MYSQL VARIABLES {{{1\n##\n# MYSQL %s " "$($MYSQLCMD -V | sed 's/.*\(Ver .*\),.*/\1/')"
printf " - By: %s@%s on %s\n" $(logname) $(hostname -f) "$(date +%c)"

perl -e "\$s=qx($MYSQLCMD -NBe 'SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES');" \
     -e 'for("aa".."uz"){$s=~s/^($_)/#\n$1/m;$s=~s/^(innodb_$_)/#\n$1/m};' \
     -e '$s=~s/(.*)\t(.*)/sprintf "# %-55s= %s",$1,$2/gem;print $s'

printf "#\n##\n# MYSQL VARIABLES }}}1\n";
```

roughly do the same what the original code.

Comment: +1, but using the character class inside of `sed` is far less interesting than letting bash do the expansion!  (And a whole lot smarter!)

Comment: While I agree your `sed` command is much simpler, I think we want each substitution happening through the `{a..u}{a..z}` expansion to occur only once and in given order. The idea behind this is to break file into stanzas containing lines starting with `aa…`, then `ab…`, etc. So we want to add new lines only before first occurence of pairs of letters.

Comment: @Ryan added an full solution

Comment: Awesome work @jm666! Is it possible to command-line-fu that into a one-liner?

Comment: @Ryan don't know commandline.fu, but feel free, ok :) Honestly, probably it can be done much better... I'm not an perl-expert ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking the command up into multiple commands:

```
 eval "$(printf "sed "; echo "-e 's,@\("{a..z}{a..z}"\),\n\n\1,'")"
```

But note that sed on OSX also probably doesn't like `\n` as a newline, so you'll have to do:

```
$ nl='
'
$ eval "$(printf "sed "; echo "-e 's,@\("{a..z}{a..z}"\),\\$nl\\$nl\1,'")"
```

I would strongly recommend finding a better solution.  Probably via `perl`.

Comment: Your fix solves the substitute error (even the first one), but when I run the entire script, it replaces t's for some reason. `wait` becomes `wai` and `thread` becomes `hread`. Can you see where/why this would happen?

Comment: @Ryan, It replaces `t` because you are substituting it out with `=` !

Comment: That replacement is happening because of the line `sed 's,\t,^= ,'`. You need to replace `\t` with a literal tab, similar to the way I replaced `\n` with a literal newline.

Comment: Different sed treat `\t` and `\n` differently, and this is a good reason to use a different tool.

Comment: I don't think the issue of differing support for control-character escape sequences such as `\n` and `\t` _by itself_ is a good enough reason to avoid `sed`: [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in `bash` (and also `ksh` and `zsh`) allows splicing in _literal_ control characters instead, which should work on all platforms. E.g., `sed 's,\t,^= ,'` would have to be written as `sed 's,'$'\t'',^= ,'`.

Answer (score 1):

For a **quick fix**, try (see below for a preferable alternative that doesn't use `eval`):

```
eval "$(echo "sed '" "s,@\("{a..u}{a..z}"\),"$'\\\n\\\n'"\1,"$'\n' "'")"
```

As @jm666 hints at, **FreeBSD `sed`** (at least the version that comes with OS X 10.9.4) has a **limit on the size of *individual* lines in a script (command string)** - 4096 bytes - and the **large *single-line* string** that results from your use of `bash`'s brace (range) expansion (`{a..u}{a..z}`) **exceeds that limit**.

The above works around that by **putting each `s` call on its own line** by appending `$'\n'` (which in `bash` expands to an actual newline - see below) rather than `;` to the string to be brace-expanded.

Also note that `\n\n` was replaced with spliced-in `$'\\\n\\\n'`, because **FreeBSD sed doesn't support `\n` escapes in replacement strings** (treats them as literal `n` chars). `$'\\\n\\\n'` inserts actual newlines - escaped with `\` - using a bash feature called [ANSI C-quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

(Similarly, **FreeBSD sed also doesn't support escape sequence `\t` in regexes** to represent  chars, so your `sed 's,\t,^= ,'` command must be replaced with `sed 's,'$'\t'',^= ,'`.)

Note that the entire string passed to `eval` must then be *double-quoted* so as to ensure that the newlines are passed through to `sed`.

<sup>Note that you could in theory still hit a limit: the max. length of a *command line*, but that limit is much higher: a little less than 256 *KB* on OS X.
Also, you may pass long `sed` scripts via a *file*, by using the `-f` option.</sup>

---

Generally, it's better to **avoid use of `eval`**, so here's an **alternative**:

```
 sed "$(printf %s "s,@\("{a..u}{a..z}"\),"$'\\\n\\\n'"\1,"$'\n')"
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I understand at last why I couldn't reproduce bug on [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851077) under Linux.

Comment: @Qeole: My pleasure; thanks for explaining why jm666's sed-only solution may not be the right approach after all (I'll revise my answer).

Comment: I proposed semething [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24855726/3716552), in case you're interested.