# Command line text find/replace for ^M (\r) and ^K (\v)

Tags: macos, bash, text, replace, sed

I'm trying to write a shell script that (among other things) will replace windows line endings (`^M`) and vertical tabs (`^K`) with new lines.  `Sed` looks like the tool to use, but I can't quite get it.  I can't see why this won't work..

```
$ sed -i 's/^K/\n/g' article_filemakerExport.xml 
sed: 1: "article_filemakerExport ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

Note: I'm working on a mac.

Comment: Does dos2unix not do what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Windows line ending, you want to remove the ^M (or `\r` or carriage return), but you want to replace the ^K with newline, it would seem.

The command I'd use is `tr`, twice.

```
tr -d '\r' < article_filemakerExport.xml | tr '\13' '\12' > tmp.$$ &&
mv tmp.$$ article_filemakerExport.xml || rm -f tmp.$$
```

Given that one operation is delete and the other substitute, I don't think you can combine those into a single `tr` invocation.  You can use `cp tmp.$$ article_filemakerExport.xml; rm -f tmp.$$` if you're worried about links, etc.

You could also use `dos2unix` to convert the CRLF to NL line endings instead of `tr`.

Note that `tr` is a pure filter; it only reads standard input and only writes to standard output.  It does not read or write files directly.

---

> Actually, I need to replace both of these with a newline.

That's easier: a single invocation of `tr` will do the job:

```
tr '\13\15' '\12\12' < article_filemakerExport.xml > tmp.$$ &&
mv tmp.$$ article_filemakerExport.xml || rm -f tmp.$$
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
tr '\13\r' '\n\n' < article_filemakerExport.xml > tmp.$$ &&
mv tmp.$$ article_filemakerExport.xml || rm -f tmp.$$
```

I don't think there's a `\z`-style notation for control-K, but I'm willing to learn otherwise (it might be vertical tab, `\v`).

(Added the `&&` and `|| rm -f tmp.$$` commands at the hinting of [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton).)

---

Partial list of control characters

```
 C Oct Dec Hex Unicode Name
\a 07   7  07  U+0007 BELL
\b 10   8  08  U+0008 BACKSPACE
\t 11   9  09  U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION
\n 12  10  0A  U+000A LINE FEED
\v 13  11  0B  U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION
\f 14  12  0C  U+000C FORM FEED
\r 15  13  0D  U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
```

You can find a complete set of these control characters at the Unicode site (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf).  No doubt there are many other possible places to look too.

Comment: In your first invocation of tr I think you need to redirect instead of specifying the filename. With that fixed your answer is better than mine since tr is standard and dos2unix is not always available.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterBowers; yes, it was missing a `<` that I know perfectly well is needed (witness the last paragraph).

Comment: Actually, I need to replace both of these with a newline.

Comment: doub1ejack, I think you will find that @JonathanLeffler's answer does just what you want. A DOS/WIndows "newline character" is actually 2 characters and when you DELETE the \r it leaves the UNIX newline character. Then in his second tr he changes \013 (^K in octal) to \12 (UNIX newline character). Therefore both the DOS newline and the ^K are converted to UNIX newlines. Try it - you'll like it... :-)

Comment: @EdMorton: fair enough...changing that, too.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work well.  What character format is '\013' and where do I look up this conversion?  ?  I also need to look up whatever `^G` is...

Comment: ^G is BEL, or `\a`, or `\007` (the James Bond character), or `\7` (these are octal constants, with or without the leading zeros).  I'll add some notes on control-character names to the main answer.  `^K` is also 'vertical tabulation', and so `\v` will probably map to that (it did for me on my Mac).

Comment: I think a \r\n will now become \n\n unless I'm mistaken - is that what is desired?  In other words, if a ^M appears at the end of the line do you want it simply deleted (leaving 1 newline) or do you want 2 newlines (by replacing the ^M with a newline)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In ascii, \a\b\t\n\v\f\r correspond to \007 - \013 in that order (or ^G - ^M, if you prefer), so \v is indeed ^K. There's probably a good mnemonic for that, but I've forgotten it.

Comment: @PeterBowers: I agree that Windows CRLF line endings and mapping CR to LF would give you double-spaced text, which is probably not what is required.  It's also possible that the data is actually coming in as (old-style) Mac lines with just CR line endings, in which case the `\r` to `\n` mapping is what is required.  It depends on the exact details of the input data.

Comment: @rici: thanks for confirming what I'd dug up from other sources too.

Answer (score 1):

```
dos2unix <article_filemakerExport.xml | tr '\013\015' '\n\n'
```

Comment: Why is dos2unix needed here?  Looks like perhaps it is just a safer way to pipe info into `tr`?  Does it do anything else to the text?

Comment: I see that it replaces dos carriage returns with newlines.  But only when they are at the end of a line.  I've got `^M` characters sprinkled throughout lines of text...

Comment: Ah, in your question you specifically mentioned windows line endings and then put ^M in parentheses. We assumed you meant real windows line endings which are actually \r\n. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A BSD (OS X) `sed` solution, assisted by [ANSI C-quoted bash strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
sed -i "" $'s/\r$/\\\n/g; s/\v/\\\n/g' article_filemakerExport.xml
```

Note:

- BSD `sed` - unlike GNU `sed` - *requires* an argument with the `-i` option; so, to indicate that *no* backup file should be created, an *empty string* (`""`) must be passed - see below for how that explains the error you got.
- The command replaces `\r\n` with `\n\n` rather than `\n`, which is what I understand you want (to get just `\n`, simply make the 2nd substitution string empty; to replace `\r` even when not followed directly by `\n`, remove the `$` after `\r`).

Here's a proof of concept with sample input:

```
$ sed  $'s/\r$/\\\n/g; s/\v/\\\n/g' <<<$'one\vtwo\r\nthree\nfour'
one
two

three
four
```

(All line breaks in the output above are `\n`.)

- An ANSI C-quoted string (`$'...'`) is needed to compensate for the lack of support for escape sequences in BSD sed: the shell creates desired control characters (`$'\v'` creates a vertical tab (`^K`; `$'\13'` would work too), `$'\r'` the CR (`^M`), `$'\n'` the newline) and passes the *resulting literals* to `sed`.
- `\\\n` results in a literal `\` followed by a literal newline - BSD `sed` requires literal newlines in the replacement string to be `\`-escaped (and doesn't support the escape code `\n`).

---

As for **why your command didn't work**:

<sup>Note: It looks like your problems stem at least in part from assuming that BSD `sed` works the same as GNU `sed`, which, unfortunately, is not the case: there are many subtle and not so subtle differences - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375</sup>

- The missing argument for the `-i` option caused `sed` to interpret your *program* as the `-i` argument, and your *filename* as the program. Since your filename starts with `a`, `sed` saw the `a` (append text) command, and choked on the rest of the filename (because it's not a valid `a` command).
- Even fixing the missing `-i` option argument wouldn't have made the command work, for the reasons listed above (in short: no support for control-char. escape sequences), and also your attempt to represent a vertical tab as string `^K` (in GNU `sed` you could have used `\v` directly).