# Using sed to change text between tags

Tags: macos, sed

I can't really figure out how to change `CHANGEME` to `CHANGED` in the file `myFile.xml` using sed, on mac.

```
<string name="myTag">CHANGEME</string>
```

I tried:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(<string name=\"myTag\">\)\(<\/string>\)/\1CHANGED\2/g" ./myfile.xml
```

but the output is just silent.
any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

- You're using *GNU* Sed syntax: in *BSD* Sed, which is the version used on OSX, `-i` *requires* and argument, even if it is the empty string (to indicate that *no* backup should be created), so **you must use `-i ''`** (note that `-i''` would *not* work for technical reasons).

  - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) for an overview of the differences between GNU and BSD Sed.
- You're not matching the *contents* of the element, [as fedorqui points out in his helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30257956/45375).

  - However, his regular expression  uses *GNU* syntax: quantifier `\+` (for *one or more* matches) is *not* supported in *BSD* Sed.
  - While you can fix this easily by replacing `\+` with a POSIX-compliant `\{1,\}`, I suggest using an *extended* regular expression with `-E` instead - see below.

---

**Unless you must remain truly POSIX-compliant** (in which case you couldn't even use `-i`), I generally **recommend using the `-E` option to activate support for *extended* regular expressions**:

- extended regular expressions are more powerful and work much more like you're probably used to from other languages (especially with respect to `+`, `?`, and `|`); notably:
- the syntax becomes cleaner (no need to `\`-escape chars. such as `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}`).

Case in point: here's **a corrected version of your command using `-E`**:

```
sed -i '' -E 's/(<string name="myTag">)[^>]+(<\/string>)/\1CHANGED\2/g' ./myfile.xml
```

Note that I've switched to ***single* quotes around the Sed script**, which is also **generally the better choice**:

- You protect the script from possibly unwanted up-front interpretation (expansions) by the shell.
- You won't have to `\`-escape `"` instances.

Comment: @AlexDarsonik you should consider accepting the answer then!

Answer (score 4):

You are not matching the block between `<string` and `</string>`. Use for example `[^<]*` to refer to everything up to a `<` is found:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(<string name="myTag">\)[^<]*\(<\/string>\)/\1CHANGED\2/g' file
<string name="myTag">CHANGED</string>
```

---

Following Dipak's suggestion, you may want to avoid writing `CHANGED` if there is not text within the `<string>` and `</string>` tags. If so, you can say `[^<]+` to make sure at least one character is found:

```
$ cat a
<string name="myTag">CHANGEME</string>
<string name="myTag"></string>
$ sed -e 's/\(<string name="myTag">\)[^<]\+\(<\/string>\)/\1CHANGED\2/g' a
<string name="myTag">CHANGED</string>
<string name="myTag"></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but since I have not earned the privilege, I am posting here

The code suggested by Fedorqui works perfectly fine and changes **CHANGEME** to **CHANGED** but also, if there is nothing between the tag it will insert **CHANGED**

You can modify the code as below in case the requirement is to leave empty tag as empty:

`sed 's/\(<string name="myTag">\)[^<].*\(<\/string>\)/\1CHANGED\2/g'`

**OR**

`sed 's/\(<string name="myTag">\)..*\(<\/string>\)/\1CHANGED\2/g' file`

In case 1 it searches for `<string name="myTag">` followed by something which does not start with `<` followed by 0 or more occurrences and replaces the same with **CHANGED**. Case 2 searches for `<string name="myTag">` followed by at least one character and replaces the same with **CHANGED**

Comment: It's a good point in general, but both `[^<].*` and `..*` are potentially too greedy in that they would match too much if a line contained more than one `</string>` instance; see what happens with `<string name="myTag">foo</string><string>another</string>'`, for instance. To fix this for _BSD_ Sed (on OSX), you'd have to use either `[^<][^<]*`, or, preferably, `[^<]\{1,\}`.