# Translate PCRE pattern to POSIX

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following pcre that works just fine:

`/[c,f]=("(?:[a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+\.(?:js|html)")/g`

It produces the desired output "foo.js" and "bar.html" from the inputs

```
<script src="foo.js"...
<link rel="import" href="bar.html"...
```

Problem is, the OS X version of grep doesn't seem to have any option like `-o` to only print the captured group (according to another SO question, that apparently works on linux). Since this will be part of a makefile, I need a version that I can count on running on any *nix platform.

I tried sed but the following

`s/[c,f]=("(?:[[:alphanum:]]|-|_|\/)+\.(?:js|html)")/\1/pg`

Throws an error: 'invalid operand for repetition-operator'. I've tried trimming it down, excluding the filepath separator characters, I just cant seem to crack it. Any help translating my pcre into something that I'm pretty much guaranteed to have on a POSIX-compliant (even unofficially so) platform?

P.S. I'm aware of the potential failure modes inherent in the regex I wrote, it only will be used against very specific files with fairly specific formatting.

Comment: There's no such thing as *"universal"* regex, FTFY ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski no but there are universal POSIX utilities like grep and sed. Problem was that grep flags are apparently platform dependent (along BSD/gnu lines) and I couldn't figure out how to do it in sed. I just can't count on pcregrep or gnu grep. Your edit was certainly cogent though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OSX following sed should work with your given input:

```
sed -E 's~.*[cf]=("[ a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+\.(js|html)").*~\1~' file

"foo.js"
"bar.html"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH8eA1/1)

Comment: That works as expected. Explanation would be helpful about how this works. It looks like you've used tilde as the separator instead of slash but I'm not sure I understand the differences between this and my original regex.

Comment: ++; it works with GNU `sed` too (GNU `sed` accepts `-E` as an alias of `-r`).

Comment: @JaredSmith: Actually it is same PCRE regex that you you had in question. I just refactored it a bit to remove remove redundant comma from first `[...]`,  converted `-|_|\/` to `[_/-]` and removed non-capturing group as that is not supported in ERE or BRE.

Comment: In other words you could also use: `sed -E 's/.*[c,f]=("([a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+\.(js|html)").*/\1/' file` with just removal of `(?:...)` as non-capturing group as that is not supported in `sed`

Answer (score 4):

**POSIX** defines **two flavors** of **regular expressions**:

- [**BREs** (*Basic* Regular Expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) - the older flavor with fewer features and the need to `\`-escape certain metacharacters, notably `\(`, `\)` and `\{`, `\}`, and *no* support for duplication symbols `\+` (emulate with `\{1,\}`) and `\?` (emulate with `\{0,1\}`), and *no* support for `\|` (alternation; *cannot* be emulated).
- [**EREs** (*Extended* Regular Expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) - the more modern flavor, which, however lacks  regex-internal back-references (which is *not* the same as capture groups); also there is *no* support for *word-boundary assertions* (e.g, `\<`) and *no* support for *capture groups*.

**POSIX also mandates which utilities support which flavor**: which support BREs, which support EREs, and which *optionally* support *either*, and which *exclusively* support only BREs, or only EREs; notably:

- `grep` uses BREs by default, but can enable EREs with `-E`
- `sed`, sadly, *only* supports BREs

  - Both GNU and BSD `sed`, however, - as a *nonstandard extension* - *do* support EREs with the `-E` switch (the better known alias with GNU `sed` is `-r`, but `-E` is supported too).
- `awk` *only* supports EREs

Additionally, the regex libraries on both Linux and BSD/OSX implement *extensions* to the POSIX ERE syntax - sadly, these extensions are in part incompatible (such as the syntax for word-boundary assertions).

As for **your specific regex**:

It uses the syntax for *non*-capturing groups, `(?:...)`; however, capture groups are pointless in the context of `grep`, because `grep` offers no *replacement* feature.

If we remove this aspect, we get:

```
[c,f]=("([a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+\.(js|html)")
```

This is now a **valid POSIX ERE** (which can be simplified - see [Benjamin W's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35690132/45375)).
However, since it is an *Extended* RE, using `sed` is *not* an option, if you want to remain strictly POSIX-compliant.

Because **both GNU and BSD/OSX `sed` happen to implement `-E` to support EREs**, you *can* get away with `sed`, if these platforms are the only ones you need to support - see [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35686968/45375).

Similarly, **both GNU and BSD/OSX `grep` happen to implement the *nonstandard* `-o` option** (unlike what you state in your question), so, again, if these platforms are the only ones you need to support, you can use:

```
$ grep -Eo '[c,f]=("([a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+\.(js|html)")' file | cut -c 3-
c="foo.js"
f="bar.html"
```

(Note that only *GNU* `grep` supports `-P` to enable PCREs, which would simply the solution to (note the `\K`, which drops everything matched so far):

```
$ grep -Po '[c,f]=\K("([a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+\.(js|html)")' file
```

)

If you really wanted **a strictly POSIX-compliant solution**, you could **use `awk`**:

```
$ awk -F\" '/[c,f]=("([a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+\.(js|html)")/ { print "\"" $2 "\"" }' file
```

Comment: I only need to worry about BSD, OS X, and linux, so the other answer is fine for my needs, but thank you for the more portable solution anyways.

Comment: @JaredSmith: My pleasure; you should accept the other answer, then.

Answer (score 2):

The [spec for POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) points out that only [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE) are supported, so no `+` or `|`; non-capturing groups aren't even in the spec for [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE).

Thankfully, both GNU sed and BSD sed support ERE, so we can use alternation and the `+` quantifier.

A few points:

- Did you really want that comma in the first bracket expression? I suspect it could be just `[cf]`.
- The expression

  ```
  (?:[a-z A-Z 0-9]|-|_|\/)+
  ```

  can be simplified to a single bracket expression,

  ```
  [a-zA-Z0-9_\/ -]+
  ```

  Only one space is needed. You can also use a POSIX character class: `[[:alnum:]]_/ -]+`. Not sure if your `[:alphanum:]` tripped sed up.
- For the whole expression between quotes, I'd just use an expression for "something between quotes, ending in `.js` or `.html`, preceded by non-quotes":

  ```
  "[^"]+\.(js|html)"
  ```
- To emulate `grep -o` behaviour, you have to also match everything before and after your expression on the line with `.*` at the start and end of your regex.

All in all, I'd say that for a sed using ERE (`-r` option for GNU sed, `-E` option for BSD sed), this should work:

```
sed -rn 's/.*[cf]=("[^"]+\.(js|html)").*/\1/p' infile
```

Or, with BRE only (requiring two commands because of the alternation):

```
sed -n 's/.*[cf]=\("[^"][^"]*\.js"\).*/\1/p;s/.*[cf]=\("[^"][^"]*\.html"\).*/\1/p' infile
```

Notice how BRE can emulate the `+` quantifier with `[abc][abc]*` instead of `[abc]+`.

The limitation to this approach is that if there are multiple matches on the same line, only the first one will be printed, because the `s///` command removes everything before and after the part we extract.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. And no, there won't be multiple matches per line, the problem is there's a conditional in a makefile I'm writing that either cats the file or strips out the regex matches, the file structure is known. As for the alphanum thing, I pulled that from some documentation site that was clearly written in the early-mid nineties.

Comment: ++; note that GNU `sed` _also_ accepts `-E` (in lieu of `-r`), even though the man page doesn't say so.

Comment: @mklement0 So it does! Interesting. Brings it in line with `grep -E`.

Comment: Yes, though, unfortunately, with `sed -E` you really have to limit yourself to the _POSIX_ ERE features (and many other POSIX-mandated `sed` behaviors - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine for the gory details) to make a given command work on both Linux and BSD/OSX; with `grep -E`, there is more overlap in the nonstandard ERE extensions.