# find a line based on string pattern and move it X places

Tags: awk, sed

I want to move the 1st instance of `AND F.col_x IS NOT NULL` pattern  ( for each of the blocks `23 24 25` etc ) that follows the `WHERE F.col_x = D.col_x` pattern either of these ways
--Look for *brackets Just before `group by`* and add it in there 
--alternately *move that line 1 line below from where it was taken*.
Either way the results would be the same

**INPUT**

```
*22 
     Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.col_x,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
              COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
    FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.col_x D 
        WHERE F.col_x = D.col_x 
        AND F.col_x IS NOT NULL
        AND D.col_x IS NOT NULL  )  
    GROUP BY   F.col_x;
    *23 
     Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.COL_y,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
              COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
    FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.DIM_DRG_CODE D 
        WHERE F.COL_y = D.COL_y 
    AND F.COL_y IS NOT NULL 
        AND D.COL_y IS NOT NULL  ) 
    GROUP BY   F.COL_y;
    *24 
     Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.COL_Z,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
              COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
    FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.COL_Z D 
        WHERE F.COL_Z = D.COL_Z 
    AND F.COL_Z IS NOT NULL 
        AND D.COL_Z IS NOT NULL  ) 
    GROUP BY   F.COL_Z;
    *25 
     Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.COL_XXX,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
              COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
    FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.COL_XX D 
        WHERE F.COL_XXX = D.COL_XXX 
    AND F.COL_XXX IS NOT NULL 
        AND D.COL_XXX IS NOT NULL  ) 
    GROUP BY   F.COL_XXX;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
*22 
 Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.col_x,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
          COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.col_x D 
    WHERE F.col_x = D.col_x 

    AND D.col_x IS NOT NULL  ) AND F.col_x IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY   F.col_x;
*23 
 Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.COL_y,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
          COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.DIM_DRG_CODE D 
    WHERE F.COL_y = D.COL_y 

    AND D.COL_y IS NOT NULL  ) AND F.COL_y IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY   F.COL_y;
*24 
 Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.COL_Z,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
          COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.COL_Z D 
    WHERE F.COL_Z = D.COL_Z 

    AND D.COL_Z IS NOT NULL  ) AND F.COL_Z IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY   F.COL_Z;
*25 
 Select   ((MYLILFUNC(F.COL_XXX,-99999)))   AS WIDTH,
          COUNT(*) AS  SIZE 
FROM    MYDB.BGSQLTB F      where NOT EXISTS ( sel '1' from  MYDB.COL_XX D 
    WHERE F.COL_XXX = D.COL_XXX 

    AND D.COL_XXX IS NOT NULL  ) AND F.COL_XXX IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY   F.COL_XXX;
```

My search pattern using Ed is a bit too wide and takes more lines and I am not sure how I can get the moving logic done because it is relative to each selected line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a couple ways. With `sed` you can do

```
sed -e '/AND F\.[a-zA-Z_]* *IS *NOT *NULL/ { h; d }; /GROUP BY/ { H; x }'
```

What happens is anytime the first regular expression matches, the `{ h; d };` commands store the line in the hold buffer and move to the next line without outputting anything. Whenever the second regexp matches, the `{ H; x }` append the current line to the hold buffer with a newline in between and then swap the hold buffer and the current line buffer. Then `sed` will automatically print out the pattern line. It's easy for this not to work correctly depending on your input, but it works fine for the sample you provided.

In `awk` it would be

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /and f.col_[a-z]* is not null/ {save = $0; next} /GROUP BY/ { print save } {print}'
```

Comment: I do not have GNU `sed` and `awk` just the POSIX plain BSD types. I hope it works with them

Comment: That last `n` doesn't do anything, does it? @user1874594 Do make the sed command work under BSD sed, you probably have to add a semicolon before the closing braces.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You're right. The `n` isn't needed. It looks like the `/I` suffix doesn't work in POSIX mode either.

Comment: I have updated the sed command to something that works in POSIX mode too.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/24276470#24276470) for everything about GNU and BSD sed differences, specifically the paragraph for "function lists". Unfortunately, the [POSIX sed standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) is not crystal clear about semicolons for one-liners ("permitted, but not required"), and BSD and GNU sed chose to implement them differently (BSD sed requires `{h;d;}`, where GNU sed is okay with `{h;d}`).

Comment: TY for helping but the SED does not work. Maybe if you can tell me a  bit more about whats happpening inside I can get it to work. 1st there is the matching part I'd like to say Find me `AND followed by any spaces followed by F. ( think the dot is to escaped right ? ) Something that is full caps followed by any spaces followed by IS followed by any spaces followed by NOT followed by any spaces followed by NULL` then let sed verify if can pick up the regex followed by the substitute part. I dont understand the substitute part the  ` h; d }; /GROUP BY/ { H; x }'`

Comment: I have updated the `sed` command to allow arbitrary space in between. If your problem gets any more complicated, you're probably going to want to use a real language like `perl` or `python` or at least use `awk`.

Comment: THanks. I am open to `awk` . Tried both and applied the modifications for `sed` to the `awk`  ( no luck as yet )..but more than this ,  I wanted to understand the logic and I much appreciate your explanation . I think, based on this , I should get it to work.  I wasn't looking  for spoon feeds and your explanation and approach answers. I am choosing ( already upped it earlier )  this. TY