# shell script not running locally

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMS05wT0VocTBYcE0) that works online, but do not work locally on terminal. What could be the possible reason? How should I debug?

```
#!/bin/bash

string='internal func add() -> Int'

sed -e '
s/^.*func \+//
s/ *\->.*$//
s/:[^,)]\+/:/g
s/[, ]//g
' <<< "$string"

echo $SHELL
```

For the input that is present in the shell script, I get `internalfuncadd()` on local computer, instead of `add()` - which is the correct output that I get online.

Comment: Try `dos2unix` on your file. The way you're using `sed` is sensitive to line terminators.

Comment: Is there a way to remove this sensitive terminators? - I'm little weak with sed and scripts as a whole.

Comment: I executed this `dos2unix fnmod.sh` where `fnmod.sh` is the filename for this script. Output remains same.

Comment: Just ran it here: got `add()`

Comment: Oh, what could be the issue, when I run `echo $SHELL` I get `/bin/zsh/` instead of online, where I get `/bin/sh/` - can this be issue? how to force it to run on `/bin/sh`

Comment: Are you using Linux, or perhaps BSD or Mac OS X? I can reproduce the error on FreeBSD.

Comment: I am using Mac OsS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using BSD sed (as comes with Mac OS X) instead of GNU sed (as is typically found on Linux). BSD sed does not support some features of GNU sed, including `\+` in basic regexes. You can instead use `\{1,\}`:

```
#!/bin/bash

string='internal func add() -> Int'

sed -e '
s/^.*func \{1,\}//
s/ *\->.*$//
s/:[^,)]\{1,\}/:/g
s/[, ]//g
' <<< "$string"
```

...or switch to extended regex flavour with `-E`, although this will require the regexes to be written in that syntax. (In this particular case, the required change is to use `+` instead of `\+`; `\+` means a literal `+` in extended syntax)

Comment: Oh wow, that works ! - Can you help me with some link to understand these stuffs ?

Comment: I don't know a comprehensive list of the differences between GNU sed and BSD sed, unfortunately.

Comment: What I can give you are links to the parts about sed and regexes in the POSIX standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html -- those are the things every sed under the sun should support. Both BSD and GNU sed extend POSIX in different ways, though. I hope that helps a little.

Comment: Nicely done. @prabodhprakash: I've tried to summarize all differences in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 - it helps.

Comment: @mklement0 I've probably linked to this answer 30 times by now ;)