# How can I split hyphen-containing words using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to split words that have hyphens in them using `sed`. Hyphens which are not inside words should stay as-is. For example, for the sentence:

```
"the multi-modal solution is an award-winning approach in the 21st-century - however"
```

I would like the output:

```
"the multi @-@ modal solution is an award @-@ winning approach in the 21st @-@ century - however"
```

I tried using:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)-\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)/\1 @-@ \2/g' test.txt > test2.txt
```

Without success. I'm using the OSX version of sed.

Comment: does your input have `-` other than between words? otherwise for given sample input, a simple `sed 's/-/ @-@ /g'` would work

Comment: the problem with your attempt is that `+` is not a meta character for default BRE... GNU sed would allow to use `\+`

Comment: my input has `-` which are not between words or in the end of words, which i wouldn't like to split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this non-regex implementation using `awk`:

```
s="the multi-modal solution is an award-winning approach in the 21st-century"
awk -F '-' -v OFS=' @-@ ' '{$1=$1} 1' <<< "$s"

the multi @-@ modal solution is an award @-@ winning approach in the 21st @-@ century
```

### **Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

**`Sed` solution (works on OSX):**

```
sed -E 's/([^-[:blank:]]+)-([^-[:blank:]]+)/\1 @-@ \2/g' <<< "$s"
```

Comment: This works, although It also splits words that end with `-` and I would like to only split words where the hyphen is in the middle

Comment: @RoeeAharoni: Try my suggested `sed` solution for that (tested on `OSX`)

Answer (score 2):

To complement the `sed -E` solution in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42271508/45375) with a fixed version of your own solution attempt:

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,\}\)-\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1 @-@ \2/g' test.txt > test2.txt
```

That is, the [ERE (*extended* regex)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) quantifier construct `+` must be emulated with `\{1,\}` in a [BRE (*basic* regex)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which `sed` uses by default.

---

#### Optional background information

As [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/sundeep) points in out in a comment on the question, *GNU* `sed` allows use of `\+` (when not using `-r` / `-E`, which enables support for EREs), but that is a nonstandard extension not supported by the macOS `sed` version.

The [`sed` POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) *only* supports *BREs*, specifically, [POSIX BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

Therefore, to write *portable* `sed` commands:

- Use neither `-r` (GNU `sed` an more recent versions of BSD `sed`) nor `-E` (both GNU and BSD/macOS `sed`)
- Use only [*POSIX* BRE features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), avoiding implementation-specific extensions, notably:

  - Use `\{1,\}` instead of `\+` (the equivalent of ERE `+`).
  - Use `\{0,1\}` instead of `\?` (the equivalent of ERE `?`).
  - Avoid GNU's `\|` for alternation: unfortunately, POSIX BREs do not support alternation at all.

To take advantage of the more powerful, modern-syntax EREs while supporting platforms with both *GNU* and *BSD* `sed` (including macOS):

- Use `-E` to enable EREs.
- Use only [*POSIX* ERE features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

---

To learn about a given `sed` implementation's specific (nonstandard) regex features:

- GNU Sed (Linux):

  - `info sed`, as of GNU Sed 4.2.2, explains

    - GNU *BRE* syntax in chapter "3.3 Overview of Regular Expression Syntax"

      - BRE extensions are `\+`, `\?`, and `\|`; that `a**` is treated the same as `a*` (without having to escape the 2nd `*`) is only true for *EREs*.
    - GNU *ERE* syntax in "Appendix A Extended regular expressions".

      - However, only the contrast with BREs is discussed, and the many ERE extensions - among them character-class shortcuts such as `\d` and `\s`, word-boundary assertions such as `\<` / `\>` and `\b`, control-character escape sequences in addition `\n`, such as `\t`, and codepoint-based escape sequences such as `\x27` - are *not* mentioned there.
  - (By contrast, `man re_format` / `man 7 regex` contain only POSIX info.)
- BSD / macOS Sed:

  - `man re_format` does apply (discusses both BREs and EREs), except for the section about *enhanced* features, which aren't supported.
  - The only extensions mentioned are word-boundary assertions `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

For a comprehensive overview of *all* differences between GNU Sed and BSD Sed, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\>-\</ @-@ /g' file
```

Replace hypens surrounded by end/start of word boundaries with the required string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  s="the multi-modal solution is an award-winning approach in the 21st-century - however"
awk -F century '{gsub(/-/," @&@ ",$1)}1'  <<< "$s" OFS=century

the multi @-@ modal solution is an award @-@ winning approach in the 21st @-@ century - however
```

Comment: This works, although It also splits words that end with `-` and I would like to only split words where the hyphen is in the middle of the word

Comment: @RoeeAharoni: Perhaps this is better?