# combine awk commands output of multiples searches display in one line

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk, sed

my input is as follow

```
<connection name="test1" transport="tcp">
<LPort>host1:11111</hostPort>
<hostPort>host1:11111</hostPort>
<abcd> 1234

<connection name="test2" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>host2:22222</hostPort>
<GPort>host1:12111</hostPort>

<connection name="xyz1" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>host3:33333</hostPort>
<FPort>host1:12113</hostPort>
<efgi> 5678

<connection name="xyz2" transport="tcp">
<LPort>host1:12234</hostPort>
<hostPort>host4:4444</hostPort>
```

I want my out put t be as follow:

```
test1  host1 1111
test2  host2 2222
xyz1   host3 3333
xyz2   host4 4444
```

To get this out put this is what I do and it works. But it seems to me there must be a better and simpler way of doing it, I did not include the entire logic ( the array ); but I have been using this method a lot when I have multiple 
searches in a file and it works. I tried to combine the awk commands using && command and it failed.

Below is part of my code & logic 
1) I cat the file
2 ) Get rid of extra character and replace with space Using sed
3 ) I take the value I want and assign to array value Using awk 
     Please note I have not included the rest of the logic ( but it works ) 
     In short I do a while loop then assign the values to 2 or 3 arrays and print them on same line to get the desired output

```
cat file  | grep -A5 connection  | sed s'/[:="><]/ /g' | awk '/name/ {print $3}'
cat file | grep -A5 connection  | sed s'/[:="><]/ /g' | awk '/hostPort/ {print $2 " " $3}'
```

If possible, please provide an alternative  solution that does not involve storing my search criteria in an array using sed/awk or any other way of doing this ?

If you can provide a solution, please provide details for each option; if you can.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus, they won't help here (at least, they should treat such structure as invalid) - the tags are in confusion (misplaced). Especially: `LPort, GPort, FPort, abcd ...`

Comment: Hi Cyrus , Thanks for your reply. I never used the parsers before and I am not sure if they apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obligatory reminder: assuming your input is well-formed XML, using an XML parser will provide a more robust solution (see bottom).

Here's a single-utility `awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS= -F '<connection name="|<hostPort>' '
  {
    sub(/".*/, "", $2)
    split($3, tokens, /[:<]/)
    printf "%-6s %s %s\n", $2, tokens[1], tokens[2]
  }
' file
```

- `-v RS=` tells `awk` to split the input into records by *paragraphs*, where a paragraph is a run of non-empty lines.
- `-F '<connection name="|<hostPort>'` splits each paragraph into fields by occurrences of `<connection name="` or (`|`) `<hostPort>`, so that the data of interest will be at the *start* of 2nd and 3rd fields (`$2` and `$3`).
- `sub(/".*/, "", $2)` removes everything following the first `"` from field 2, effectively leaving just the connection name.
- `split($3, tokens, /[:<]/)` splits the 3rd field into an array of tokens by occurrences of `:` and `<`, yielding the host name in the 1st array element and the port in the 2nd.
- `printf "%-6s %s %s\n", $2, tokens[1], tokens[2]` prints an output line, right-padding the connection name to at least 6 characters with spaces, as in your sample output; simply omit the `-6` if you just want a single space to separate the output fields.

---

#### Optional reading: XML-parsing utilities (CLIs) usable in shell scripts

- [**`xmllint`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) is ***preinstalled* on *some* platforms**:

  - **macOS/FreeBSD/PC-BSD** (possibly other BSD variants)
  - ***some* Linux** distributions: **Fedora**, **CentOS**
  - On others, a package may be available; e.g., on Ubuntu:
    `sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils`
  - **Caveat**: While `xmllint` supports [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) queries, it **allows virtually no control over the output format**.
- ***Install-on-demand* alternatives - superior to `xmllint`:**

  - **[`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)**

    - `xmlstarlet` is powerful and flexible, supporting a wide range of operations.
    - **macOS**: Install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with `brew install xmlstarlet`
    - **Linux**: chances are that it can be installed with your platform's package manager; e.g., on Debian-based distros such as **Ubuntu**:
      `sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet`
    - **Windows**: download and install manually from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/files/xmlstarlet/).
  - **[`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html)**

    - `xidel` requires manual [download and installation](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads), but its power and flexibility make up for this inconvenience.
    - Supports **Linux**, **macOS**, and **Windows**

---

Below are **solutions that contrast the 3 utilities listed above**.

The following well-formed XML document is assumed to be contained in `file` - note how the `<connection>` elements are now enclosed in a single, top-level `<doc>` element:

```
<doc>
  <connection name="test1" transport="tcp">
    <LPort>host1:11111</LPort>
    <hostPort>host1:11111</hostPort>
    <abcd>1234</abcd>
  </connection>

  <connection name="test2" transport="tcp">
    <hostPort>host2:22222</hostPort>
    <GPort>host1:12111</GPort>
  </connection>

  <connection name="xyz1" transport="tcp">
    <hostPort>host3:33333</hostPort>
    <FPort>host1:12113</FPort>
    <efgi>5678</efgi>
  </connection>

  <connection name="xyz2" transport="tcp">
    <LPort>host1:12234</LPort>
    <hostPort>host4:4444</hostPort>
  </connection>
</doc>
```

---

#### `xmllint` solution:

`xmllint`'s lack of control over formatting of the query results requires a nontrivial `awk` helper command:

```
echo 'cat //connection/@name | //hostPort/text()' | xmllint --shell file | awk -F\" '
  NR % 2 { next }                  # skip separator lines
  NR % 4 == 2 { conn = $2; next }  # save connnection name
  { 
    split($0, tokens, ":")
    printf "%-6s %s %s\n", conn, tokens[1], tokens[2] 
  }
'
```

---

#### `xmlstarlet` solution:

`xmlstarlet`'s `sel` sub-command supports very flexible extractions by translating options into XLST templates behind the scenes:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t  -m '//connection' -v 'str:align(@name, "      ")' \
           -o ' ' \
           -c 'str:replace(hostPort, ":", " ")' -n file
```

---

#### `xidel` solution:

`xidel` is very flexible and not only supports XML, but also HTML and JSON.

While it has no support for XLST, it supports [XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery), a superset of XPath with XSLT-like features, which enables powerful transformations.<sup>Tip of the hat to [Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703456/reino).</sup>
As far as I can tell, there is no function for padding, however, so a - straightforward - auxiliary `awk` command is used:

```
xidel file -q --xquery \
  'for $c in //connection return concat($c/@name, " ", replace($c/hostPort, ":", " "))' |
    awk '{ printf "%-6s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

That said, XQuery even supports *user-defined* functions, so you can write your own padding function:

```
xidel -q file --xquery '
  declare function pad($s as xs:string?) as xs:string 
  {
    substring(concat($s, "      "), 1, 6)
  }
  for $c in //connection return concat(pad($c/@name), " ", replace($c/hostPort, ":", " "))
'
```

Comment: @Reino: I've changed it to what you see now because it (a) works with the sample XML document I've posted (note the enclosing `<doc>` element, which is missing from the document you use in the linked page) and (b) it works on _Linux_, which is what this question is about (your commands assume _Windows_). As for why your comments disappeared: I've flagged them as _obsolete_, because the points made in them have been incorporated into the answer. While I cannot _personally_ make comments disappear, _moderators_ agreed with my assessment, which is what actually made them disappear.

Comment: @Reino: I've made it clearer that I've enclosed the `<connection>` elements in a single, top-level element. You are correct about the equivalence, but you need to be mindful of the context of the question. At first, before I looked into XQuery, I blindly tried your command as-is, not realizing that the quoting wouldn't work on _Unix_ platforms.

Answer (score 0):

With single ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n '/<connection/{N;N; s/<connection name="\([^"]*\)".*<hostPort>\([^:]*\):\([^<]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/p}' file
```

The output:

```
test1 host1 11111
test2 host2 22222
xyz1 host3 33333
xyz2 host4 4444
```

---

- `N;N;` - append the next 2 lines to the pattern space (including newlines)
- `connection name="\([^"]*\)` - capturing *connection name*
- `<hostPort>\([^:]*\):\([^<]*\)` - capturing *host name* and *port number*

Comment: Hi Roman - I did attempt to use this however got the following error >>> bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: @theuniverseisflat, check your command for typos. It works fine

Comment: I copy and pasted ur command ; however I am on my mac computer not at work maybe there is something with the shell used . however I try it at work.   thanks again

Comment: @theuniverseisflat, as you added `linux` tag - it'll work on linux. You did not say anything about macos

Comment: question if there are more than 2 lines referring to ur command N;N; lets say 3 or 5 ; how would you change this? I never used this before? And what shell are you in?

Comment: No I do not use this on macos shell. I use it at work, But I am not there today. I can use KSH or Bourne shell. I will try it there as well.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat, you have already accepted the answer. what this conversation for?

Comment: I am just trying to learn various ways of doing the same thing. If you do not wish to continue I understand. I hope to learn from you a bit about your approach and using SED.  I accepted the answer because it offered an answer that worked . Thanks again for ur time.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat: With a single-quoted `sed` script (`'...'`), which specific (POSIX-like) shell you're using is irrelevant; what matters is the implementation of `sed` you're using, and there are significant differences between the BSD implementation found on macOS and the GNU implementation found on Linux - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

To merge blank line separated blocks and extract desired values from each block using backreferences:

```
sed '${/^$/!{H;s/.*//;};};/^$/!{H;d;};/^$/{x;s/^\n<connection name="\([^"]*\)".*<hostPort>\([^:]*\):\([^<]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/;};' file
```

Comment: Hi SlePort I tried to use ur command but I get the following error also could u please provide more detail? cat file |  sed '${/^$/!{H;s/.*//;}};/^$/!{H;d;};/^$/{x;s/^\n<connection name="\([^"]*\)".*<hostPort>\([^:]*\):\([^<]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/;}'   extra characters at the end of } command

Comment: You must escape parentheses in BRE  mode: `\(` and `\)` or use the `-E` flag: `sed -E`. And you don't need to pipe your sed to `cat`. Just copy and paste my sed command to test it.