# Compatibilty with sed for both Linux and MacOs

Tags: linux, macos, sed

On Linux, I have a Bash script in which I am using `sed`. In this script, I am using substitutions with "`sed -i`".

Unfortunately, on MacOS, this version of `sed` is not the same as Linux `sed`.

I am looking for a way to use a compatible sed on Linux and MacOS, i.e having the same script for both OS.

Could you tell me if using `gsed` for both OS instead of `sed` allows to have a unique compatible version for this script (where `gsed -i` works on both)

### Update 1

In my case, on MacOS 10.9.5, I would like to replace the `line 2` of a file by the value of a variable. I tried :

```
a=2
sed -i'' -e "2c\$a" file.dat
```

but the line is replaced by `"$a"` and not the value of a=`2`.

What can I try next?

PS: I would like to get a Linux/MacOS portable command line.

Comment: Could you just not use the `-i` flag and do a `mv -f your_sed_output your_original_file` after your sed? then you don't have to monkey around with installs and prayers.

Comment: You can use `sed -i.bak '....'` and it will work same on both Lunux and MacOS

Comment: `gsed` on BSD (Darwin, MacOS) or Solaris for that matter  would stand for GNU sed, which is the same as `sed` shipped with most Linux distributions. Unfortunately, I do not think that (all) Linux distributions would also have the g prefixed name (mine doesn't) for it (btw. same story `awk`, `tar` and others).

Comment: `Perl` can do everything `sed` can do, and far more besides, and is more orthogonal and consistent between platforms, including Solaris too.

Comment: I did an **update 1** of my question, if anyone could see what's wrong ... thanks

Comment: Your "update" is a new/different question.

Comment: let say that I precise in this update the substitution command that I speak about into my original post.

Comment: How about `sed -e "2s|.*|$a|" file.dat`

Comment: -@MarkSetchell great ! that seems to work on both Linux/MacOS : could you tell me please what the different pipe symbols do ?

Comment: The separator after `s` can be any punctuation character; `/` is commonly used as the canonical separator but you can choose any separator you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately a large number of behaviors in `sed` which are not adequately standardized. It is hard to articulate a general answer which collects all of these.

For your specific question, a simple function wrapper like this should suffice.

```
sedi () {
    case $(uname -s) in
        *[Dd]arwin* | *BSD* ) sed -i '' "$@";;
        *) sed -i "$@";;
    esac
}
```

As you discovered, details of the `c` command are also poorly standardized. I would simply suggest

```
sedi "2s/.*/$a/" file.dat
```

where obviously use a different separator if `$a` could contain a slash; or if you are using Bash, use `${a//[\/]/\\/}` to backslash all slashes in the value.

Other behaviors which differ between implementations include extended regex support (`-r` or `-E` or not available), the ability to pass in multiple script fragments with `-e` (the portable solution is to separate commands with newlines), the ability to pass standard input as the argument to `-f`, and the general syntax of several commands (does the filename argument of the  `r` and `w` commands extend up to the next whitespace, semicolon, or newline? Can you put a command immediately adjacent to a brace? What are the precise semantics of backslashed newlines and where are they mandatory? Where are backslashes before command arguments mandatory?) and obviously regex flags and features.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/ which has an excellent answer with much more details.