# Using sed to find replace in a file but not on lines matching multiple patterns

Tags: regex, sed

I have an `XML` file that I am finding and replacing `emails` and `usernames` in.
It's all good but to avoid some duplicate user emails etc.. I am wanting to skip XML elements of specific types.

I can do this if I want to skip ONE specific time i.e.

```
/ApplicationUser/!s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g
```

But not if I try multiple on the one sed command

```
/(OtherElement|ApplicationUser)/!s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g
```

OR

```
/\(OtherElement\|ApplicationUser\)/!s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g
```

OR

```
/\(OtherElement|ApplicationUser\)/!s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g
```

I am loading in the commands from a file if that is relevant. I'm assuming it has something to do with my pattern at the start trying to match 1 or more words but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

So, the regular expression syntax depends on the version of sed you're using.

First off, according to the POSIX specification, [basic regular expressions (BRE) do not support alternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards). However, tools do not necessarily follow the specification and, in particular, different versions of sed have different behavior.

The examples below are all processing this file:

```
$ cat sed-re-test.txt
OtherElement "user.name"
OnlyReplaceMe "user.name"
ApplicationUser "user.name"
```

#### GNU sed

The GNU sed BRE variant supports alternation but the `|` metacharacter (along with `(` and `)`) must be escaped with a `\`. If you use `-E` flag to enable Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), then the metacharacters *must not* be escaped.

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
<...SNIP...>
```

GNU sed BRE variant (with escaped metacharacters): **WORKS**

```
$ cat sed-re-test.txt  | sed '/\(OtherElement\|ApplicationUser\)/!s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g'
OtherElement "user.name"
OnlyReplaceMe "user.name@abc.com"
ApplicationUser "user.name"
```

GNU sed ERE (with unescaped metacharacters): **WORKS**

```
$ cat sed-re-test.txt  | sed -E '/(OtherElement|ApplicationUser)/!s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g'
OtherElement "user.name"
OnlyReplaceMe "user.name@abc.com"
ApplicationUser "user.name"
```

#### BSD/MacOS sed

BSD sed does not support alternation in BRE mode. You must use `-E` to enable alternation support.

No `--version` flag, so identifying the OS will have to do:

```
$ uname -s
OpenBSD
```

BSD sed BRE (with escaped and unescaped metacharacters): **DOES NOT WORK**

```
$ cat sed-re-test.txt  | sed '/\(OtherElement\|ApplicationUser\)/! s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/'
OtherElement "user.name@abc.com"
OnlyReplaceMe "user.name@abc.com"
ApplicationUser "user.name@abc.com"

$ cat sed-re-test.txt  | sed '/(OtherElement|ApplicationUser)/! s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/'
OtherElement "user.name@abc.com"
OnlyReplaceMe "user.name@abc.com"
ApplicationUser "user.name@abc.com"
```

BSD sed ERE  (with unescaped metacharacters): **WORKS**

```
$ cat sed-re-test.txt  | sed -E '/(OtherElement|ApplicationUser)/! s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/'
OtherElement "user.name"
OnlyReplaceMe "user.name@abc.com"
ApplicationUser "user.name"
```

Comment: BRE do support alternation.. like `()` it needs escaping `\|`

Comment: oops, I thought `\|` was part of POSIX spec.. anyway, here's a comprehensive comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/

Comment: That's a great comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/OtherElement\|ApplicationUser/b;s/"user.name"/"user.name@abc.com"/g file
```

On encountering a line which you do not want to process, break out, fetch the next and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk and avoid the convoluted, backwards logic (`if X do NOT do Y but do Y for everything else` vs the simple `if NOT X do Y`) and the version-specific constructs that you get with sed.

```
awk '!/OtherElement|ApplicationUser/{ gsub(/"user.name"/,"\"user.name@abc.com\"") } 1' file
```

That is clear, simple, extensible and will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.