# macos sed subsitute command on MacOS Sierra failing

Tags: macos, sed

I'm feeling really stupid about asking this. I should know why this is failing. The following command works as expected in linux but not on MacOS Sierra:

```
echo "ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=750 DEFAULT" | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]\+//'
```

On linux the command results in:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
```

I've tried to various iterations of this command and cannot get it to work. I know that MacOS's sed is the BSD version instead of the GNU version but this substitute command should still work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The suggested duplicate answer does solve my problem but in a densely worded, roundabout way. The TL;DR version is thusly:

MacOS uses BSD-style sed. The solution is to simply use the -E option (extended regular expressions) which doesn't require escaping certain characters (like the + symbol). This method also works just fine with GNU-style sed found on most Linux systems. I hope this helps somebody down the road.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed not giving me correct substitute operation for newline with Mac - differences between GNU sed and BSD / OSX sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference)

Comment: `\+` is the difference.. try `sed -E 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]+//'`

Comment: Yes! I knew it had to be simple. The full command should be `echo "ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=750 DEFAULT" | sed -E 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]+//'`. Thank you Sundeep!

Comment: I should mention that this command works perfectly on both Linux and MacOS with the -E command and not escaping the + symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BRE instead of an ERE. This will work using any sed in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ echo "ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=750 DEFAULT" | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9][0-9]*//'
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
```

Comment: Well, since I am dealing with AUTO_INCREMENT the number of digits could be 2 or 10. Appreciate your idea though.

Comment: The code I posted will work just fine no matter how many digits it has. Try it. `[0-9][0-9]*` is the BRE equivalent of EREs `[0-9]+` and **every** sed, even the very old default one on Solaris, will support that format.