# Bash / Sed / Grep : Parsing / Capturing a Substring

Tags: bash, macos, sed, grep, substring

I have generated a set of filepaths as strings in a bash script, all of this form:

`./foo/bar/filename.proto`

There can be any number of subfolders/slashes, but they all have the `.proto` extension.

I want to trim the leading `./` and trailing `filename.proto` to transform them to look like this:

`foo/bar`

I have had a surprising amount of difficulty adapting this from other solutions and debugging it.  I have tried:

```
grep -Po "\.\/(.*)\/[^\/]+\.proto"
```

and

```
sed -n 's/\.\/\(.*\)\/[^\/]+\.proto/\1/p'
```

I have tried sed with both escaped and unescaped parentheses.  For reference, I am currently working on a mac, and would like the most cross-platform-compatible solution.

I could do this fairly easily in Python, but I want to avoid the complexity of calling another script to do this.

To give you an idea of how this is working, my full script looks like this (so far):

```
#!/bin/bash
consume_single_folder () {
  do_stuff $1
}

find . -name \*.proto|while read fname; do
  echo "$fname" |sed -n 's/\.\/\(.*\)\/[^\/]+\.proto/\1/p' | consume_single_folder
done
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:

To be clear, I have tested my regex on regex101.com and it seems to look alright:

```
\.\/(.*)\/[^\/]+\.proto
```

It should be greedy, capturing everything between the first and last slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `dirname` could help you:

```
$ dirname "./foo/bar/filename.proto"
./foo/bar
```

With leading `./` removal:

```
$ dirname "./foo/bar/filename.proto"  | sed "s/\.\///g"
foo/bar
```

Also you could add `sort | uniq` avoid duplicates:

```
find . -name \*.proto|while read fname; do
  echo "$fname" | xargs dirname | sed "s/\.\///g" | consume_single_folder
done
```

Works on MacOS and Linux

Comment: Replace echo by dirname and remove the xargs

Comment: good idea of using dirname, could simplify to `consume_single_folder "$(dirname ${fname#./})"`

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use sites like regex101 for testing `sed` regular expression - syntax and features vary a lot between tools, as well as between various implementations.. See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) and [differences between various sed implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/)

For your given example, changing `+` to `*` will work (lookup differences between BRE and ERE)

```
$ fname='./foo/bar/filename.proto'
$ echo "$fname" | sed -n 's/\.\/\(.*\)\/[^\/]*\.proto/\1/p'
foo/bar
$ # or use a different delimiter
$ echo "$fname" | sed 's|\./\(.*\)/[^/]*\.proto|\1|'
foo/bar
$ # further simplification as find already filters by extension
$ echo "$fname" | sed 's|\./\(.*\)/.*|\1|'
foo/bar
```

Also, I would suggest to read [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) and change your `find` syntax accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your solution and for your links!  I especially liked the idea to use a different delimiter.  I decided to go with the approach that you mentioned in the other answer.