# Parsing JSON with BusyBox tools

Tags: json, regex, grep, cut, busybox

I'm working on a blog theme for Hugo installable on Android (BusyBox via Termux) and plan to create a BusyBox Docker image and copy my theme and the hugo binary to it for use on ARM.

Theme releases are archived and made available on NPM and the [tools available](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) on BusyBox have allowed me to reliably parse `version` from the metadata from JSON:

```
meta=$(wget -qO - https://registry.npmjs.org/package/latest)
vers=$(echo "$meta" | egrep -o "\"version\".*[^,]*," | cut -d ',' -f1 | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d '" ')
```

Now I would like to copy the `dist` value from the `meta` into a text file for use in Hugo:

```
"dist": {
  "integrity": "sha512-3MH2/UKYPjr+CTC85hWGg/N3GZmSlgBWXzdXHroDfJRnEmcBKkvt1oiadN8gzCCppqCQhwtmengZzg0imm1mtg==",
  "shasum": "a159699b1c5fb006a84457fcdf0eb98d72c2eb75",
  "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/after-dark/-/after-dark-6.4.1.tgz",
  "fileCount": 98,
  "unpackedSize": 5338189
},
```

*Above pretty-printed for clarity. The [actual metadata](https://registry.npmjs.org/after-dark/latest) is compressed.*

Is there a way I can reuse the `version` parsing logic above to also pull the `dist` field value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper robust parsing requires tools like `jq` where it could be as simple as `jq '.version' ip.txt` and `jq '.dist' ip.txt`

You could use `sed` but use it at your own risk

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"version":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' ip.txt
6.4.1

$ sed -n 's/.*\("dist":{[^}]*}\).*/\1/p' ip.txt
"dist":{"integrity":....
....}
```

- `-n` option to disable automatic printing
- the `p` modifier with `s` command will allow to print only when substitution succeeds, this will mean output is empty instead of entire input line when something goes wrong
- `.*"version":"\([^"]*\).*` this will match entire line, capturing data between double quotes after `version` tag - you'll have to adjust the regex  if whitespaces are allowed and other valid json formats
- `.*\("dist":{[^}]*}\).*` this will match entire line, capturing data starting with `"dist":{` and first occurrence of `}` afterwards - so this is not suited if the tag itself can contain `}`

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks, Sundeep. Thoughts on making this portable to BSD sed?

Comment: I don't have BSD sed to test it, but I feel this should work on any sed... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/ for further help..

Comment: The first of the two works on BSD, whereas the second results in empty output. Both work fine on BusyBox, which is what I asked for. I'll dig into the differences in sed using the relevant link you provided. Thanks again for your help.