# "sed" doesn't match pattern

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to format cut, paste output but sed not working.

**file.txt**

```
Apple
Banana
Apple
Banana
Orange
Apple
Orange
```

**code.sh**

```
cut -f2 file.txt | sort | uniq | sed 's/^\|$/#/g'| paste -sd,\& -
```

**expected output / output on ubuntu**

```
#Apple#,#Banana#&#Orange#
```

**getting output / output on macos**

```
Apple,Banana&Orange
```

**Note:** The code works on Ubuntu, but on MacOS it doesn't.

Comment: FYI you can combine `sort | uniq` to `sort -u`

Comment: macos sed probably doesn't support `\|`.. you can try `sed -E 's/^|$/#/g'` see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/24276470#24276470

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with `cut`, `sort`, `uniq`, and `paste`. You could reduce the whole example to `echo foo | sed 's/^\|$/#/g'`

Comment: @Sundeep Weirdly, that inserts `#` at the beginning of each line, but not the end.

Comment: @Barmar weird indeed, I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work

Comment: Why `cut -f2`? The file only has one field.

Comment: @Barmar Yes `sort -u` is working on Mac but does it work on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Sundeep Yes that worked, thanks.

Comment: Why not install `gsed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere, BSD `sed` doesn't support `\|`. Instead of replacing `^` and `$`, you can substitute `#` *around* the whole line.

```
sort -u file.txt | sed 's/.*/#&#/' | paste -sd,'&' -
```

Comment: Thanks for `sort -u` but does it work with ubuntu?

Comment: It should work everywhere, it's a standard `sort` option that long predates all the different flavors of Unix.

Comment: I realised that your solution is properly working, but tell me one thing why you replaced `$` with `&` in `s/.*/#&#/`. With `$` it doesn't work.

Comment: `&` is replaced with whatever the regexp matched, which is the whole line.

Comment: `$` only has meaning in the regexp, not the replacement.

Comment: Right, `-u` is a required argument for POSIX `sort`, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html, and has been present in every sort I remember using for the past 40+ years.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk '!seen[$1]++{} END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
    for (i in seen)
      s = s (s == "" ? "" : (++j==1?",":"&")) "#" i "#"
    print s
}' file

#Apple#,#Banana#&#Orange#
```

On OSX I have `gnu awk` installed via `home brew`.

Comment: Looks good, I have home brew, but I don't use awk.

Comment: It is super easy to install then `brew install gawk`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, BSD/Mac `sed` doesn't support `\|`. See [sed not giving me correct substitute operation for newline with Mac - differences between GNU sed and BSD / OSX sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275070/sed-not-giving-me-correct-substitute-operation-for-newline-with-mac-difference/24276470#24276470) for details.

As an alternate, you can use ERE instead of BRE. I checked it on Linux, apparently this still doesn't seem to work on Mac (See also: [MacOS sed: match either beginning or end](https://superuser.com/questions/1420166/macos-sed-match-either-beginning-or-end)).

```sh
$ echo 'Apple' | sed -E 's/^|$/#/g'
#Apple#

# workaround for Mac
$ echo 'Apple' | sed -e 's/^/#/' -e 's/$/#/'
#Apple#
```

Instead of `sort+uniq+sed`, you can also use `awk` (but note that `awk` solution shown here removes duplicates while preserving original order, doesn't `sort` the input):

```sh
$ awk '!seen[$0]++{print "#" $0 "#"}' ip.txt
#Apple#
#Banana#
#Orange#
```

Change `$0` to `$2` if you want only the second field, based on your use of `cut`

Comment: Maybe it depends on the OS version, but on 10.13.6 the `sed` command produces just `#Apple`

Comment: @Barmar I have only Linux, so can't test it elsewhere. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sundeep and @Barmar - see https://superuser.com/a/1420167, you're hitting the `s/^|$/#/g` bug in sed on MacOS.

Comment: Good find @EdMorton

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. I'm sure there's other posts out there that provide C&V as I I've come across this before, I was just too lazy to look for them!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it using the sed command:

```
sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+/#&#/'
```

- the -**E** option for enabling the POSIX ERE (extended regular
  expression)
- **[[:alnum:]]+** The alphanumeric characters; in ASCII, equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9] with the plus **(+)** to refer to one or more.
- the **&** symbol, does bring or refer to the content of the pattern we found. (on which we surrounded it with #)