# Explanation of difference between GNU sed and BSD sed

Tags: sed, gnu, bsd, gnu-sed

I wrote the following command

```sh
echo -en 'uno\ndue\n' | sed -E 's/^.*(uno|$)/\1/'
```

expecting the following output

```
uno
```

This is indeed the case with my GNU Sed 4.8.

However, I've verified that BSD Sed outputs

Why is that the case?

Comment: I'm not sure I would have the same expectations.  Regexes are greedy.  Because of that, the `.*` should always match the entire line, so that inside the parens matches the end of line.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/3266847) goes in-depth about the differences between various sed implementations.

Comment: Just a guess here: it looks like the GNU ERE regex engine is willing to backtrack farther to find the longer match ("uno"), whereas the BSD regex engine is happy enough to let `.*` consume the whole line, and then capture `($)` the empty string.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I'm pretty sure _Mastering Regular Expressions_ gives examples of engines where alternation is not greedy nor lazy, but ordered.

Comment: `perl` gives empty lines too. I think this depends on implementation, and as linked above, there are plenty of differences between `GNU` and `BSD`

Comment: @TimRoberts quantifiers in BRE/ERE are not exactly greedy though, longest match wins. For example, `echo 'foo123312baz' | grep -oE 'o[123]+(12baz)?'` gives `o123312baz` whereas you'll get `o123312` with greedy quantifiers like those in PCRE

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that BSD's sed is POSIX-compatible only. POSIX specifies support only for basic regular expressions, which have many limitations (e.g., no support for | (alternation) at all, no direct support for + and ?) and different escaping requirements.

BSD sed is default one on MacOS so very first thing on a new system is to get GNU-compatible sed: `brew install gsed`.

Comment: BSD sed is not POSIX-compatible only. BSD sed does support extended regular expressions.