# How to add a line of text containing the filename to all text files recursively in terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed, terminal

I have a bunch of javascript files and I need to add a comment on a new line at the beginning of every file that contains the filename e.g.

```
/* app.js */
```

I'd like to do this recursively on a folder from the terminal on my mac.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, we have to locate those files:

```
$ find $folder_name -type f -name "*.js" -print
```

This will locate all of the files with the suffix of `*.js`. The `type -f` means only look for files (just incase you have a directory name that ends in `.js`). I will assume that your JavaScript file names don't contain whitespace, or control characters like `<NL>` characters in the name. Otherwise, we'll have to do a bit more work.

We can use that [find](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) statement to locate all of those files, then we can munge those files. Once we find those files, we have to figure out how to munge the file to get the comment line on top.

We'll take  three step approach:

1. First, we'll create a new file with the comment line in it.
2. Next we'll concatenate the old file on the end of the new file.
3. We'll rename the new file to the old file.

For the first step, we'll use [echo](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/echo.1.html) to create a new file with the old name. Then, we'll use the [cat](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cat.1.html) command to concatenate the old file on the new file. And, finally we'll use [mv](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mv.1.html) to *rename* the newly constructed file to the old name.

```
find $javascript_dir -type f -name "*.js" -print | while read file_name
do
    basename=$(basename $file_name)
    echo "/* $basename */" > "$basename.tmp"
    cat "$file_name" >> "$basename.tmp"
    mv "$basename.tmp" "$file_name"
done
```

Note that `>` redirects the output of the command to the named file, and that `>>` appends the output of the command to the named file. `mv` stands for *move*. In Unix, file are actually stored by inode identify. There's a table of contents that matches the inode to the full name of the file (including the directory). Thus, moving a file in Unix is the same as simply renaming it, so the directory name is changed. In Windows batch, there are separate `move` and `rename` commands. In Unix, they're both `mv`.

---

## Addition

We could use `sed` to do an in place prepending of the line:

```
find . -name "*.js" -print | while read file_name
do
    basename=$(basename $file_name)
    sed -i "" "1i\\
    /* $basename */
    " "$file_name"
done
```

`sed` is a powerful line editor, and most people use only its *substitution* command mode. However, `sed` scripts can be way more complex and rich (and obscure which is why you rarely see them).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat -` and a temp file:

```
# adds filename to top of each file in $DIR
DIR=. # set to whatever directory
FILES=$(find $DIR -type f)
for FILE in $FILES; do 
  FILE=$(echo $FILE | sed -e s/\.\\\///) # remove leading "./" if DIR is "."
  echo "/* $FILE */" | cat - $FILE > tempfile.tmp # add the line using a temp file
  mv tempfile.tmp $FILE # move the temp file back to the original file
done
```

Note that this will add the full path of the file relative to DIR if DIR is not '.'.   To add only the filename itself you could use:

```
  echo "/* $(basename $FILE) */" | cat - $FILE > tempfile.tmp # add the line using a temp file
```

Comment: If you're going to use the `find` command, why find the files, then use a `for` loop to loop through them? Just pipe a `while read` loop to the end of the of the `find` command. I do like piping the `cat` to the end of the `echo` command.

Comment: Sure, you could just pipe the `find` output to `while read`.  I just added the intermediate FILES variable for clarity and readability.  FILES could be any list of files generated by `ls`, `find`, or any other function or script.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sed for this, try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find ./ -name *.js);
do
 `sed -i 's/$i \*\//$i \*\/\n&/' "$i"`
done
```

Insert a newline with sed could be a problem since not all version works the same. To have an overview see this [reference](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html). You can for example replace the substitution part with `G` or `{G;}`. It depends on your sed version.
Similar Questions are already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363030/how-do-i-insert-a-newline-linebreak-after-a-line-using-sed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern)

**Another interesting solution:**

If you want to append a newline after the first line you can also use this:

```
sed -i "1a\ " test.js
```

So change the script above into this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find ./ -name *.js);
do
 `sed -i "1a\ " $1`
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to get this to run from inside a shell script. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a command I can run from the command line?

Comment: Have you tested this script? Your loop is going to increment over the words `find`, `./`, `-name`, and then all files in the current directory that end in `*.js`. You also have capitalized `For`, `Do`, `Sed`, and `Done`. Finally, why use _substitution_ in a `sed` script if you really want to _insert_  a line?

Comment: Sorry i was underway so i hadn't tested and on android app the word starts on each new line with capital letter.

Comment: If you used `1i\` rather than `1a\` in your script, it would prepend the line. You also shouldn't use *back ticks* around the `sed` command.  Plus, the inserted/appended line goes on the _next_ line. And, for Mac's version of `sed`, you need a null quote after the `-i`. Note when you put the `sed` in a shell script, you have to double up the backslash. See my answer.

Comment: @DavidW. thanks for the suggestions but I want to use 1a since the problems i told before. Why i shouldn't use `? It works for me. Also the double backslash is not necessary tested on arch linux.