# sed or egrep regex multiple line

Tags: sed, grep

I have a LaTeX-File like this:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
          urlcolor=black
]
{hyperref}
\usepackage{ngerman}
```

and i have to output it like this:

```
hyperref:colorlinks,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black
ngerman:
```

I may only use sed and egrep, not awk and perl.
How do I do this?

Comment: why can you only use sed and egrep?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I tried this one: sed -e '$!N;s#\,\n#\,#' tmp.tex | sed -e 's/\\usepackage\([[]\(.*\)[]]\)*{\(.*\)}/\3:\2/g' It matches the second one, but not the one on multiple lines. I think the first sed is wrong somehow...

Comment: And I think I have to remove every newline until the first "}".

Comment: Ok I got something else for newline-removing:
sed '/\,$/N;s/\n//' tmp.tex But this one removes only every 2nd newline.

Comment: yes sed only could certainly do the trick but you need to be more explicit with the conversion you want. Ex: why urlcolor is no more in output

Comment: Oops, i will change this. EDIT: Changed.

Comment: And my Output should be: "Thing in curly brackets":"things in square brackets"

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe `sed` command into other `sed` commands to use a layered approach.

1. Remove newlines
2. Convert } into }\n
3. Convert `\usepackage[optional]{packagename}` into `packagename:[optional]`
4. Remove the spaces and brackets

Here is the script:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.latex | sed 's/}/}\n/g' | sed 's/\\usepackage[[:space:]]*\(.\+\)\?[[:space:]]*{\(.\+\)}/\2:\1/' | sed 's/\[//g;s/\]//g;s/[[:space:]]//g'
```

Here is the result:

```
hyperref:colorlinks,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black
ngerman:
```

The first command is taken verbatim from [How to insert a newline in front of a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern). Some of these commands can be combined, but I find it easier to understand when there is a separate command for each step. If your latex files are small, time should not be a problem.