# find particular tag on a xml string

Tags: xml, linux, unix, grep

I have a big transaction log file. Under that are XML response strings  (especially on erricson IN log). I want the response code and this value only. Currently when I grep this on linux all the complete string is coming.

Below is my log entry:

```
2015-05-18 13:01:33,817 UserMsisdn=919813290710,:: CustomerMsisdn=919671055440Stage is TOP:: After reading complete data from IN::<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodResponse><params><param><value><struct><member><name>accountAfterRefill</name><value><struct><member><name>accountFlags</name><value><struct><member><name>activationStatusFlag</name><value><boolean>1</boolean></value></member><member><name>negativeBarringStatusFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceFeePeriodExpiryFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceFeePeriodWarningActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>supervisionPeriodExpiryFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>supervisionPeriodWarningActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member></struct></value></member><member><name>accountValue1</name><value><string>9058</string></value></member><member><name>offerInformationList</name><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>expiryDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>20150520T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value></member><member><name>offerID</name><value><i4>2220</i4></value></member><member><name>offerType</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member><member><name>startDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>20150505T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>expiryDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>99991231T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value></member><member><name>offerID</name><value><i4>2692</i4></value></member><member><name>offerType</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member><member><name>startDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>20100226T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>serviceClassCurrent</name><value><i4>2742</i4></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferings</name><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>1</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>2</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>3</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>4</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>5</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>6</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>7</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>8</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>9</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>10</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>11</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>12</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>13</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>14</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>15</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>16</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>17</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>18</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>19</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>20</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>21</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>22</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>23</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>24</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>25</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>26</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>27</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>28</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>29</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>30</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member><member><name>serviceOfferingID</name><value><i4>31</i4></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>usageAccumulatorInformation</name><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>accumulatorID</name><value><i4>2212</i4></value></member><member><name>accumulatorValue</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>accumulatorID</name><value><i4>2253</i4></value></member><member><name>accumulatorValue</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member></struct></value></member><member><name>availableServerCapabilities</name><value><array><data><value><i4>537207364</i4></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>currency1</name><value><string>INR</string></value></member><member><name>languageIDCurrent</name><value><i4>1</i4></value></member><member><name>masterAccountNumber</name><value><string>9671055440</string></value></member><member><name>negotiatedCapabilities</name><value><array><data><value><i4>0</i4></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>originTransactionID</name><value><string>HR1573404963</string></value></member><member><name>refillType</name><value><i4>3</i4></value></member><member><name>**responseCode</**name><value**><i4>0</i4></**value></member><member><name>segmentationID</name><value><string>N200</string></value></member><member><name>transactionAmount</name><value><string>8600</string></value></member><member><name>transactionCurrency</name><value><string>INR</string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodResponse>
```

Below is the command I used for this, but it is not working properly:

```
grep 'responseCode' TransactionLog.log.21_05_2015-12|egrep "<member>.*</member>"
```

Expected output will be:

```
responseCode</name><value><i4>0</i4>
```

Answer (score 0):

The log entries are very long lines of XML. The `grep` command only finds whole lines that contain a matching pattern. The `grep` command has found a matching line and outputs it for you - it is just that it is a very long line.

You want to extract just a part of the line that it has found. That is best done with another tool, such as `perl` or `awk`. You could also use `sed` to chop the single line into many lines at the member tag and then grep for the particular item you wanted.

Using sed to **add** newlines is a bit awkward, but it is explained in this question/answer: [How to insert a newline in front of a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern)

To break the line at every <member> clause you can write this:

```
sed -e 's/<member>/\'$'\n<member>/g'
```

Then you can select only the ResponseCode section, giving:

```
grep responseCode Transaction.log | sed -e 's/<member>/\'$'\n<member>/g' | grep responseCode
```

The output generated is now:

```
<member><name>**responseCode</**name><value**><i4>0</i4></**value></member>
```

You can now chop that down a bit more with sed:

```
grep responseCode Transaction.log | sed -e 's/<member>/\'$'\n<member>/g' | grep responseCode | \
sed -e 's/<member><name>//g' -e 's/<\/name>//g' -e 's/<\/value>//g' -e 's/<\/member>//g'
```

.. and now it should be trivial to get the format that you actually want.

Comment: i have also tried grep 'responseCode' TransactionLog.log.21_05_2015-12|sed -e "s/<value>\(.*\)<\/value>/\1/" command with sed but all lines are comming .

Comment: @sunil4ur_s1 I've written the code for you. See edited answer