# Trying to print "\n" in bash with sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Having some problems having sed insert the two-character sequence <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>. (I'm using bash to create some expect scripts).  Anything that I try in a replace pattern ends up as an actual newline character.

I've tried:

```
sed s/<string>/'\\\\n'/
sed s/<string>/\\\\n/
sed s/<string>/\\n/
```

And pretty much any permutation that does or doesn't make any sense.

I need it to work with the bash and sed installed on a Mac.

Comment: Which version of `sed`? The GNU and bsd versions process escape sequences quite a bit differently, and I'm not sure about others...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern

Comment: @ergonaut This isn't a dup, it's the opposite of that question.

Comment: how is it the opposite?  The other question's answer points to the same answer stated by @chepner.

Comment: @ergonaut That's not what the current question asks for -- it asks for a backslash followed by "n" in the output, rather than a linefeed. The other question is about getting a linefeed instead of backslash and "n".

Comment: @leechb's 2nd line of code works for me..

Answer (score 1):

`sed s/<string>/'\\n'/` works for me with both the Lunix (GNU) and OS X (bsd) versions of `sed`:

```
$ echo aXb | sed s/X/'\\n'/
a\nb
```

`sed s/<string>/\\\\n/` would also work. When bash sees `\\` (outside of quotes), it treats it as a single escaped backslash, so `\` is actually passed to the command. When it sees `\\\\n`, that's just two escaped backslashes followed by "n", so it passes `\\n` to the command. Then, when `sed` sees `\\n`, it also treats that as an escaped backslash followed by "n", so the replacement string winds up being `\n`. Since the "n" is always *after* any completed escape sequence, it's just treated as another character in the replacement string.

Comment: for me `echo 122 | sed 's/2/\\n/g'` works on AIX, SUN, RHEL

Answer (score 0):

pure code, single quoted

```
sed 's/Pattern/\\n/' YourFile
```

Shell interpreted, double quote

```
sed "s/Pattern/\\\\n/" YourFile
```

Comment: OP doesn't want a newline. What is wanted is literally a backslash followed by an n.

Comment: oops :-) i will adapt, sorry