# How to copy an entire line which matches the string and paste right after it?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I am trying to search for a particular line in a file using grep command and I am successful doing that. Now I want to copy the entire line to a new line right after the original line. In other words, the original line should be followed by the new line with same content.

For example:
Original data:

```
Apple 

Samsung

Nokia

HTC
```

Say if I want the new data to look like

```
Apple

Samsung

Samsung

Nokia

HTC
```

I tried grep and pipe with sed and I failed. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: grep <string> input.txt


This will read the entire line if it matches with the string. Now I want to copy the buffer into a new line which comes after the original line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/H;//G' file
```

If the pattern can occur more than once:

```
sed 'x;z;x;/pattern/H;//G' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you can turn off printing lines by default with `-n` and display lines with `p`. Using this information will show the solution

```
sed '/Samsung/p' yourfile
# Or, when you want to match the whole line
sed '/^Samsung$/p' yourfile
```

Comment: What does `-n` have to do with this question?

Comment: @glennjackman This is the first time I use the option `p` without `-n`. For people who do not know the `p` option it is a small hint how `p` can be used in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

To copy the entire line matching pattern, and to past it on the new line, right after that:

```
sed -i $'s/.*Samsung.*/&\\\n&/' file
```

The output:

```
Apple
Samsung
Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

To output the result to another file.

```
sed $'s/.*Samsung.*/&\\\n&/' file > anotherfile
```

Answer (score 0):

For a file `input.txt` with the contents

```
Apple
Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

You can do inline replacement a duplicate the lines 'Samsung' like this:

```
sed -i 's/\(Samsung\)/\1\n\1/' input.txt
```

The parentheses capture the word, then `\1` puts it back twice with a newline in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed $'s/Samsung/&\\\n&/' input.txt
```

Outputs:

```
Apple
Samsung
Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

---

See also:

- [How to insert a newline in front of a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern)

Comment: Hi codeforester,

thank you for your help. I gave a very simple example as the data but in my case I have a pretty lengthy line and it is not convenient to type the entire line each as I have to do this multiple times in my file. I was thinking to use grep, match the pattern, and then copy the entire line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Or this sed: `sed '/Samsung/ {h;G}' file`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

```
awk '/Samsung/ {print}; {print}' file
perl -pe 'print if /Samsung/' file
```