# sed replacement which adds a newline

Tags: shell, sed

I have string like

```
990202-1711-BBVRS390-T01
415715-1611-EDUE818C,1711-EDUE818C
415715-1611-EDUE818C-,1711-EDUE818C-T01
```

I want to replace all ,  with newline and first 7 character so that the output is

```
990202-1711-BBVRS390-T01
415715-1611-EDUE818C
415715-1711-EDUE818C
415715-1611-EDUE818C-
415715-1711-EDUE818C-T01
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You may want to take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Angus Chiang --  Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here is `awk` apporach:

```
awk '{firstSeven=substr($0,1,7);gsub(/,/,RS firstSeven)}1' inputfile
990202-1711-BBVRS390-T01
415715-1611-EDUE818C
415715-1711-EDUE818C
415715-1611-EDUE818C-
415715-1711-EDUE818C-T01
```

Exaplanation:

`substr` function : This function is used to get the first seven characters.From 1st character to 7th character.
`gsub` function: This function is used to replace a comma with New line followed by firstSeven Characters. Here `RS` is used to get new line as the default vale of `RS` is new line.

To do the changes inside the file use `-inplace` option of awk ,if it is not available :

```
awk '{firstSeven=substr($0,1,7);gsub(/,/,RS firstSeven)}1' inputfile >inputfile.tmp && mv inputfile.tmp inputfile
```

Comment: The only (?) problem with that is it'd fail if the replacement string contained backreferences, e.g. `&`. Doesn't LOOK like that can occur for the OPs case though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{7})([^,]+),(.*)$/\1\2\'$'\n''\1\3/' file
```

Output:

```
990202-1711-BBVRS390-T01
415715-1611-EDUE818C
415715-1711-EDUE818C
415715-1611-EDUE818C-
415715-1711-EDUE818C-T01
```

---

See also:

- [How to insert a newline in front of a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern)

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Are you using a Unix/Linux shell to run this?

Comment: :/opt/edirscript/dualrole #                                                                                        sed -E "s/^(.{7})([^,]+),(.*)$/\1\2\'$'\n''\1\3/" DualRoleAccounts.dat2
sed: invalid option -- E
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

Comment: Why did you use `$` and `\3`? Have a look at my answer!

Answer (score 0):

using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.\{7\}\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1\2\n\1\3/g' filename
```

in **regex** . means every character;
`\(.\{7\}\)` - with that i mark first 7 characters.
`\([^,]*\)` - with that i mark from 8th character part of line that not containing comma.
`,\(.*\)` - with that there will be comma and with `.*` i mark all other characters from after comma to end of line.
`\1\2` - and backslash and number i can use marked part of line (first marked will be `\1`, second `\2` and so on.).

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F',' '{pfx=substr($0,1,7); $1=substr($1,8); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print pfx $i}' file
990202-1711-BBVRS390-T01
415715-1611-EDUE818C
415715-1711-EDUE818C
415715-1611-EDUE818C-
415715-1711-EDUE818C-T01
```