# Adding new line in regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to add new line at the begin of my regular expression but i don't know how to do it. This is my regular expression

`(?:"name":")(.*?)(?:")|(?:"text":")(.*?)(?:")`

Answer (score 0):

use the following regex

```
s/(\d{5})/\r\n\1/gs
```

or

```
s/(?<=\D)(\d{5})(?=\D|$)/\n\1/g
```

Comment: I want to use my regular expression and at the begin of my regular expression i want to   add new line space

Comment: which language you are using? can you post your code?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern

Comment: i need it to filter json data