# Format git diff with newline spacing

Tags: git

Is it possible to add newlines or somehow format the output of `git diff` when called from the terminal?

Here is an excerpt from one of my `git diff`'s, where after the previous file diff (ending at the last +), the next file diff starts.

```
+    def loader_collatefn(self, batch_list):
+        return data.dataloader.default_collate(batch_list)
+
+    def __getitem__(self, idx):
+        pass
+
+    def __len__(self):
+        pass
+
diff --git a/dataload/mrds_dataset.py b/dataload/mrds_dataset.py
index 9a5d60a..b751bc7 100644
--- a/dataload/mrds_dataset.py
+++ b/dataload/mrds_dataset.py
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@ 
 from PIL import Image

 from . import DataPhase
+from . import BaseDataset
```

But, I think it would be more readable if there were a few newlines between each individual file's diff so that I can more easily see when the next file starts if I'm scrolling through the diff quickly.
Is there a git config option for this?

Comment: that sounds more like something you would do by processing diff output, actually. That output format is pretty much standard *patch* format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try piping diff output into this:

```
git diff blah blah blah | sed 's/^diff/\n\n\ndiff/'
```

That will create the separation

Comment: That's good, but on some systems (like my Mac) it's tricky to get `sed` to recognize newlines. For example, on my machine your `\n\n\ndiff` pattern are printed like `nnndiff`. There are ways, but sometimes it's easier to just [give up on `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23790355/643383) and use `perl` instead: `git diff foo foo2 | perl -pe 's/(diff --git)/\n\n\n$1/'`. Awk is another good option.