# How do I omit metadata in git diffs?

Tags: git

in a normal git diff, output may look like this:

```
diff --git a/app/index.html b/app/index.html
index f1a34ce..723dc5c 100644
--- a/app/index.html
+++ b/app/index.html
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
 
     {{content-for "head"}}
 
+    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/tailwind.css">
     <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css">
     <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/my-app.css">
```

is there a way to omit this:

```
index f1a34ce..723dc5c 100644
--- a/app/index.html
+++ b/app/index.html
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
```

So that all that's left is:

```
diff --git a/app/index.html b/app/index.html
 
     {{content-for "head"}}
 
+    <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/tailwind.css">
     <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css">
     <link integrity="" rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/my-app.css">
```

This is the best I've been able to come up with:

```sh
git diff \
  | sed -n '/^---/!p' \
  | sed -n '/^+++/!p' \
  | sed -n '/^@@/!p'  \
  | sed -n '/^index /!p'
```

But there *has* to be a better way?

Comment: You could write an alias that would find those lines by pattern and remove them. Would that do? (You'd need to believe there's a regular expression that would express the pattern, and you'd need to accept the use of an alias rather than seeking some sort of built-in `diff` modifier.)

Comment: yeah, just hoping there'd be something built in to git somewhere

Comment: I don't think there is. :) But the alias makes the notion of piping thru sed a lot less unpleasant. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685295/git-diff-dictate-extra-blank-line-between-files

Comment: There's a shorter one, though. `git diff | sed '/^diff/,/^@@/ {/^diff/!d}'`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable when calling `git diff`, as explained in `git(1)`:

> When the environment variable GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is
> set, the program named by it is called to generate
> diffs, and Git does not use its builtin diff machinery.
> For a path that is added, removed, or modified,
> GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is called with 7 parameters:
>
> path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

Write a small shell-script that starts your favorite `diff` between `old-file` and `new-file` and ignores the other arguments.