# Unable to put data to the first line in terminal without an editor?

Tags: unix, terminal

Duplicate of [prepend to a file one liner shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365/prepend-to-a-file-one-liner-shell) .

I trying to put my paste to the very first line without opening an editor similarly as but for the reverse direction

```
echo Masi >> file
```

**How can you put data to the first line in terminal without opening an editor?**

For instance,

I have a file

```
M
M
M
```

I want to put Masi to my file such that

```
Masi
M
M
M
```

without opening an editor in terminal.

Comment: On what system? Using Unix standard tools?

Comment: Antony: Using standard Unix tools. I use Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: sorry, I can't understand the question.  Can you please expand it?

Comment: Definitely a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365/prepend-to-a-file-one-liner-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with `ed`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/ed $1 <<__EOT__
1i
Masi
.
wq
__EOT__
```

Technically, this *is* firing up an editor, but it's non-interactive, so may meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
mv file temp_file
echo "Masi" > file
cat temp_file >> file
rm temp_file
```

Write a script if you have to do it a lot...

---

Or I believe you *could* do it with `ed`. You'll have to decide for yourself if you think that counts as "opening an editor"...