# Redirect output from sed 's/c/d/' myFile to myFile

Tags: bash, sed, solaris, redirect

I am using sed in a script to do a replace and I want to have the replaced file overwrite the file.  Normally I think that you would use this:

```
% sed -i 's/cat/dog/' manipulate
sed: illegal option -- i
```

However as you can see my sed does not have that command.

I tried this:

```
% sed 's/cat/dog/' manipulate > manipulate
```

But this just turns manipulate into an empty file (makes sense).

This works:

```
% sed 's/cat/dog/' manipulate > tmp; mv tmp manipulate
```

But I was wondering if there was a standard way to redirect output into the same file that input was taken from.

Comment: How come no one mentioned `sponge`?

Comment: I guess the question was not [sponge-worthy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sponge).

Comment: a call from 2020: why `sed 's/cat/dog/' manipulate > manipulate` makes an empty file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I commonly use the 3rd way, but with an **important change**:

`sed 's/cat/dog/' manipulate > tmp && mv tmp manipulate`

I.e. change `;` to `&&` so the move only happens if sed is successful; otherwise you'll  lose your original file as soon as you make a typo in your sed syntax.

**Note!** For those reading the title and missing the OP's constraint *"my sed doesn't support `-i`"*:  For most people, sed will support `-i`, so the best way to do this is:

`sed -i 's/cat/dog/' manipulate`

Comment: `sed -i ...` is [merely `sed 's/cat/dog/' manipulate > tmp && mv tmp manipulate` under the covers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276651/sed-with-inplace-editing-changes-group-ownership-of-file).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `-i` is also supported in FreeBSD/MacOSX `sed`, but needs the empty string as an argument to edit a file in-place.

```
sed -i "" 's/old/new/g' file   # FreeBSD sed
```

Comment: `-i` don't need empty string. Value of the parameter is backup extension to use, when it's empty string - no backup will be done. On GNU sed the default value for `-i` is empty string.

Comment: It's my life saver

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to move copies around, you could use ed:

```
ed file.txt <<EOF
%s/cat/dog/
wq
EOF
```

Comment: does ed support all of the regular expressions that sed does?  Specifically ranges?

Comment: ed supports all of the regular expressions that sed does, including ranges.

ed - works on files
sed - works on streams

The other main difference is that an ed command, by default will only work on the current line of a file (which is why I edited my example and added the %, to make the command run on all lines), while sed commands, by default, run against all lines.

Comment: you can also use "ex", which is alias to "vim". It's very feature-rich.

Answer (score 3):

Kernighan and Pike in *The Art of Unix Programming* discuss this issue.  Their solution is to write a script called `overwrite`, which allows one to do such things.

The usage is: `overwrite` *`file`*  *`cmd`*  *`file`*.

```
# overwrite: copy standard input to output after EOF

opath=$PATH
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

case $# in
0|1)   echo 'Usage: overwrite file cmd [args]' 1>&2; exit 2
esac

file=$1; shift
new=/tmp/overwr1.$$; old=/tmp/overwr2.$$
trap 'rm -f $new $old; exit 1' 1 2 15  # clean up

if PATH=$opath "$@" >$new
then
       cp $file $old           # save original
       trap '' 1 2 15          # wr are commmitted
       cp $new $file
else
       echo "overwrite: $1 failed, $file unchanged" 1>&2
       exit 1
fi
rm -f $new $old
```

Once you have the above script in your `$PATH`, you can do:

```
overwrite manipulate sed 's/cat/dog/' manipulate
```

To make your life easier, you can use `replace` script from the same book:

```
# replace: replace  str1 in files with str2 in place
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

case $# in
    0|2) echo 'Usage: replace str1 str2 files' 1>&2; exit 1
esac

left="$1"; right="$2"; shift; shift

for i
do
    overwrite $i sed "s@$left@$right@g" $i
done
```

Having `replace` in your `$PATH` too will allow you to say:

```
replace cat dog manipulate
```

Comment: Or in this case simply download a new version of sed, compliant with -i option, from www.sunfreeware.com ;)

Comment: +1, the overwrite script is very useful (after a few changes according to personal preferences)!

Comment: @Anders: Replacing the system sed with a non-standard alternative, however free it may be, may not be a viable option, nor does it answer the question of how to do it with available/standard tools.

Comment: The POSIX standards - which Solaris follows - only dictates a minimum set of option for sed to be compliant, so GNU/Sed or whatever you like to call is actually compliant with what you call "standard tools".

Comment: @Anders, It is compliant with POSIX, but if you use a non-POSIX option, then of course you are not relying on *standard* tools.  One can of course install GNU sed on a system, but then one might not be able to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sponge` from the [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/).

```
sed "s/cat/dog/" manipulate | sponge manipulate
```

Comment: for me, this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `-i` is gnu sed, or just an old version of sed, but anyways. You're on the right track. The first option is probably the most common one, the third option is if you want it to work everywhere (including solaris machines)... :) These are the 'standard' ways of doing it.

Comment: `-i` is also supported in FreeBSD/MacOSX `sed`

Answer (score 1):

To change multiple files (and saving a backup of each as *.bak):

perl -p -i -e "s/oldtext/newtext/g" *

```
replaces any occurence of oldtext by newtext in all files in the current folder. However you will have to escape all perl special characters within oldtext and newtext using the backslash 

This is called a “Perl pie” (mnemonic: easy as a pie)
The -i flag tells it do do in-place replacement, and it should be ok to use single (“'”) as well as double (“””) quotes.

    If using ./* instead of just *, you should be able to do it in all sub-directories 
See man perlrun for more details, including how to take a backup file of the original.
using sed:
            sed -i    's/old/new/g' ./*  (used in GNU)
    sed -i '' 's/old/new/g' ./*  (used in FreeBSD)
```

Answer (score 0):

`-i` option is not available in standard `sed`.

Your alternatives are your third way or `perl`.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of answers, but none of them is correct. Here is the correct and simplest one:

```
$ echo "111 222 333" > file.txt
$ sed -i -s s/222/444/ file.txt 
$ cat file.txt
111 444 333
$
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated that the `-i` flag is considered "illegal" by his version of `sed`. So it cannot be used...

Answer (score -2):

Workaround using open file handles:

```
exec 3<manipulate
```

Prevent open file from being truncated:

```
rm manipulate
sed 's/cat/dog/' <&3 > manipulate
```

Comment: While technically correct and a cute trick, this is **dangerous**. If your power fails just after while `sed` is executing, you'll end up with missing data.

Comment: Just link elsewhere before you remove and it'll be fine.