# How to update the version of a file?

Tags: c++, callback

I have a server where I upload sometimes the new version of my software.
For each upload, I have to incremente the build var contained in a file.ver, like #BUILD 345.
Well, I cannot do this everytime manually, but I prefer a smart and fast solution, that increment the number of the version for each upload.

What's the easiest way?
There is in bash a nice command to do that?
Or a callback method written in C/C++?

Comment: Do you mean source control such as SVN, Perforce, Git??

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986521/bumping-version-numbers-for-new-releases-in-associated-files-documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `sed` to replace strings in a file.

For example, if you have a file `myfile` with the following content:

```
// Some comments
// Version: #VERSION
// ...
```

You can use the following command to replace the version number:

```
sed -i 's/#VERSION/123/g' myfile
```

The `-i` means *inline*, i.e. modify the file content.

> *Do not* redirect the output of sed back to the same file, as in `sed ... myfile > myfile` as you will lose the file contents. See [Redirect output from sed 's/c/d/' myFile to myFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585438/redirect-output-from-sed-s-c-d-myfile-to-myfile)

Result:

```
// Some comments
// Version: 123
// ...
```

If you use Ant, this could be useful:

[Use ANT to update build number and inject into source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439876/use-ant-to-update-build-number-and-inject-into-source-code)

See also the following question related to version numbering (schemes):

[Bumping version numbers for new releases in associated files (documentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986521/bumping-version-numbers-for-new-releases-in-associated-files-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be easy you should use the IDE or makefile for this otherwise will probably forget it sometimes.

Depends on which system OS ,  ... your using, but most IDEs have this feature
VisualStudio can do this or you create a small script in your makefile.