# How to add Git's branch name to the commit message?

Tags: git, bash, git-branch

I need some help with a Bash script that will automatically add the git's branch name as a hash in commit messages.

Comment: For anyone coming here is seems the best answer is at the bottom of the page

Comment: Side note: all the `git branch | grep ...` for getting the current branch are the wrong way to do this. Consider either `git symbolic-ref -q HEAD` (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270862/1256452)) or `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`. The symbolic-ref command will fail if you're on a detached HEAD, so if you wish to detect that case, use it. Otherwise the rev-parse --abbrev-ref method is probably best.

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Unless by “bottom of the page” you meant that the best answer will always be the most recent one then I don’t think that’s what you meant (for posteriety).

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Yeah uh which one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524807/930875

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the `prepare-commit-msg` or `commit-msg` [githook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

There are examples already in your `PROJECT/.git/hooks/` directory.

As a security measure, you will have to manually enable such a hook on each repository you wish to use it. Though, you can commit the script and copy it on all clones into the `.git/hooks/` directory.

Comment: I don't need to, you already have an example that does **exactly what you want**, as I already said, in `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample`. =) All you need to modify (after following the directions in the comments) is to copy-paste whatever solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch you'd like

Comment: @ninjagecko, for me `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample` contains three examples. One for commenting out conflicts section, adding `git diff --name-status -r` output to it and adding Signed-off-by lines... No adding branch name to the commit message. So I was forced to write my own hook.

Comment: Does this `you will have to manually enable such a hook on each repository you wish to use it` mean that you have to give the FILE execute permissions? If so, may I edit the answer to include that (or could you, please)?

Comment: @DanRosenstark: I think the .git/hooks folder is not tracked (at least by default) and one may need a manually copy the files into the .git/hooks folder (or have a script to do it) or some other homebrew custom method. For what I meant, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457031/tracking-changes-to-hooks-in-git-hooks . Also to answer your question: the sample files in the .git/hooks directory don't seem to suggest adding +exec permissions (though I do see some sites saying you might need exec permissions; thus I don't know the exact answer to your question).

Comment: @ninjagecko okay, we'll leave this as is for now, but for ME on osx, changing permissions to 755 on the particular file in the hooks directory worked for me. However, in the end I went with an older solution, which doesn't use hooks at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086896/including-the-current-branch-name-in-the-commit-template/4316350#4316350 ... which only covers some part of the current question, but anyway... Thanks!

Answer (score 203):

Here is my `commit-msg` script as an example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# Automatically adds branch name and branch description to every commit message.
#
NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') 
DESCRIPTION=$(git config branch."$NAME".description)

echo "$NAME"': '$(cat "$1") > "$1"
if [ -n "$DESCRIPTION" ] 
then
   echo "" >> "$1"
   echo $DESCRIPTION >> "$1"
fi
```

Creates following commit message:

```
[branch_name]: [original_message]

[branch_description]
```

I'm using issue number as `branch_name`, issue description is placed to the `branch_description` using `git branch --edit-description [branch_name]` command.

More about branch descriptions you can find on this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git).

The code example is stored in following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3132078).

Comment: This script squashes multi line commit messages to a single line.  I replaced your echo statement with: echo -n "$NAME"': '|cat - "$1" > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out "$1"

Comment: Put this file into the folder PROJECT/.git/hooks/

Comment: It works well. But for Mac, I had to set the permission too to make it work: >>> sudo chmod 755 .git/hooks/commit-msg

Comment: @ManojShrestha yes it has to be executable

Comment: @AlexSpence more simply you could use `echo $NAME: "$(cat $1)" > $1`. This works because the reason the newlines were being lost is that echo was treating each line of `$(cat "$1")` as a new argument and echoing each with a space between.  By surrounding `$(cat "$1")` with double quotes, echo treats the cat output as a single argument.  Also I don't think it is necessary to quote `$1` since its value is `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

Comment: I get `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.` upon `git commit`

Comment: Might be helpful to mention that this is also a git hook

Comment: How to add this to a submodule hook? Since I get error `cat: .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG: Not a directory`

Answer (score 44):

A bit simpler script that adds the branch name to the commit message **before** you edit it. So if you want want to change or remove it you can.

Create this file **.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg**:

```
#!/bin/bash

branchPath=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD) #Somthing like refs/heads/myBranchName
branchName=${branchPath##*/}      #Get text behind the last / of the branch path

firstLine=$(head -n1 $1)

if [ -z "$firstLine"  ] ;then #Check that this is not an amend by checking that the first line is empty
    sed -i "1s/^/$branchName: \n/" $1 #Insert branch name at the start of the commit message file
fi
```

Comment: I get: `sed: 1: ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG": invalid command code .` when using this.

Comment: Aha, Mac OSX difference, see: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=393450&postcount=11 for the fix

Comment: like the checking of the amend and fixup case

Comment: OSX : Needs file extension to work if you're getting the above error message. `sed -i '.bak' "1s/^/$branchName : \n/" $1`

Comment: You can use `@` as a `sed` separator instead of `/` since forward slashes are more likely to show up in the branch name or commit message, screwing up `sed`.

Comment: @OryBand the branchName is the text behind the last slash, i.e. it will never contain a slash

Comment: @Pylinux it failed for me on a branch name called `ory/SERVER-111-bla-bla`

Comment: @OryBand then it's not that branchName contains slash that is the issue, run this in a *nix cmd `branchPath=ory/SERVER-111-bla-bla; echo ${branchPath##*/}` and you'll se that the branchName don't contain slashes.

Comment: @Pylinux than why did replacing `/`s with `@`s solve the problem? nothing else included slashes.

Comment: @OryBand did you verify that the branchName variable contained slashes? The only job of line two is to remove "folders" from the branch.

Comment: @Pylinux it does contain slashes, but I want the branch to *keep* the slashes e.g. `ory/SERVER-111-bla-bla`. If I execute line 2 than the `ory/` part will be removed, and I don't want that.

Comment: @Pylinux I now understand what you were talking about. You're doing remove prefixed parts with `/`s from the branch name, thus avoiding the case I had. [I skipped the substitution in my version](https://gist.github.com/oryband/da880c74b6b8e7433adf), and didn't notice this until now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :-)

Comment: AFAICT this assumes that the message comes from `-m`: I needed to remove the `if` to get it to work with a message generated by a template.

Comment: @snakecharmerb This is meant to be used _without_ `-m`, i.e. just with `git commit` and the editor setup in git (usually vim). Pretty sure `-m` will override what we are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 31):

You can do it with a combination of the prepare-commit-msg and pre-commit hooks.

**.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg**

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH=`git branch | grep '^\*' | cut -b3-`
FILE=`cat "$1"`
echo "$BRANCH $FILE" > "$1"
```

**.git/hooks/pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/bash

find vendor -name ".git*" -type d | while read i
do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                DIR=`dirname $i`
                rm -fR $i
                git rm -r --cached $DIR > /dev/null 2>&1
                git add $DIR > /dev/null 2>&1
        fi
done
```

**Set permissions**

```
sudo chmod 755 .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
sudo chmod 755 .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Comment: Note that this can remove the original commit message if you're using `--amend` for example. Instead of using `echo` you should use `sed` instead. Here it is in a one liner: `sed -i "1s@^@$(git branch | grep '^\*' | cut -b3-) @" $1`

Answer (score 16):

add the below code in prepare-commit-msg file.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Automatically add branch name and branch description to every commit message except merge commit.
#

COMMIT_EDITMSG=$1

addBranchName() {
  NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') 
  DESCRIPTION=$(git config branch."$NAME".description)
  echo "[$NAME]: $(cat $COMMIT_EDITMSG)" > $COMMIT_EDITMSG
  if [ -n "$DESCRIPTION" ] 
  then
     echo "" >> $COMMIT_EDITMSG
     echo $DESCRIPTION >> $COMMIT_EDITMSG
  fi 
}

MERGE=$(cat $COMMIT_EDITMSG|grep -i 'merge'|wc -l)

if [ $MERGE -eq 0 ] ; then
  addBranchName
fi
```

It will add branch name to commit message except merge-commit. **The merge-commit has branch information by default** so extra branch name is unnecessary and make the message ugly.

Comment: So this will not amend the commit message when it find the word merge on the message ?

Comment: @thoroc that is technically correct; however, in normal use this isn't a big deal. The commit message being parsed is the "default ones" prior to you editing them. So as long as your commit template doesn't have the word "merge" in it, I believe you should be okay (as long as the other "default" messages don't except for a default merge commit message). I misunderstood this originally, and believe I have it correct now.

Answer (score 8):

In case you want the JIRA ticket added to the commit message use the script bellow.

Commit message something like `PROJECT-2313: Add awesome feature`
This requires your branch name to start with the jira Ticket.

This is a combination of this solutions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270862/1256452
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-and-git-prepare-commit-msg/qaq-p/254173#M20824

It is modified for OS X, with the `sed -i '.bak'` and it works as well from SourceTree.

https://gist.github.com/georgescumihai/c368e199a9455807b9fbd66f44160095

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# A hook script to prepare the commit log message.
# If the branch name it's a jira Ticket.
# It adds the branch name to the commit message, if it is not already part of it.

branchPath=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD) #Somthing like refs/heads/myBranchName
branchName=${branchPath##*/}      #Get text behind the last / of the branch path

regex="(PROJECTNAME-[0-9]*)"

if [[ $branchName =~ $regex ]]
then
    # Get the captured portion of the branch name.
    jiraTicketName="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

    originalMessage=`cat $1`

    # If the message already begins with PROJECTNAME-#, do not edit the commit message.
    if [[ $originalMessage == $jiraTicketName* ]]
        then
        exit
    fi

    sed -i '.bak' "1s/^/$jiraTicketName: /" $1 #Insert branch name at the start of the commit message file
fi
```

Comment: This is working good on client side file : prepare-commit-msg to auto populate commit prefix. But if I want to do the same on the server side hook, which is bitbucket server (in my case) and I am trying to add this logic on pre-receive hook at the Bitbucket server path : BITBUCKET_HOME/shared/data/repositories/<repository-id>/hooks/21_pre_receive , it is not working as "git symbolic-ref -q HEAD" giving 'master' though I am committing from my feature/abc branch from client side. Is there another way here?

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by Tim's answer which builds upon the top answer, it turns out the prepare-commit-msg hook takes as an [argument what kind of commit is occurring](https://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html). As seen in the default prepare-commit-msg if $2 is 'merge' then it is a merge commit. Thus the case switch can be altered to include Tim's addBranchName() function.

I've included my own preference for how to add the branch name, and all the uncommented parts of the default `prepare-commit-msg.sample` hook.

> prepare-commit-msg

```
#!/bin/sh

addMyBranchName() {
  # Get name of current branch
  NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')

  # First blank line is title, second is break for body, third is start of body
  BODY=`cut -d \| -f 6 $1 | grep -v -E .\+ -n | cut -d ':' -f1 | sed '3q;d'`

  # Put in string "(branch_name/): " at start of commit message body.
  # For templates with commit bodies
  if test ! -z $BODY; then
    awk 'NR=='$BODY'{$0="\('$NAME'/\): "}1;' $1 > tmp_msg && mv tmp_msg "$1"
  else
    echo "title\n\n($NAME/):\n`cat $1`\n" > "$1"
  fi
}

# You might need to consider squashes
case "$2,$3" in
  # Commits that already have a message
  commit,?*)
  ;;

  # Messages are one line messages you decide how to handle
  message,)
  ;;

  # Merge commits
  merge,)
    # Comments out the "Conflicts:" part of a merge commit.
    perl -i.bak -ne 's/^/# /, s/^# #/#/ if /^Conflicts/ .. /#/; print' "$1"
  ;;

  # Non-merges with no prior messages
  *)
    addMyBranchName $1
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make it global (for all projects):

Create `git-msg` file with the content of [shytikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524807/1735406), and put it in some folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.git_hooks
# make it executable
chmod a+x ~/.git_hooks/commit-msg
```

Now enable hooks:

```
git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git_hooks'
```

and `git init` again in each project you want to use it.

Comment: I found that to use this feature, I had to put 'commit-msg' into a 'hooks' directory inside the directory configured for 'init.templatedir' so that when the whole templatedir gets copied on 'git init', 'commit-msg' ends up in the project's '.git/hooks' directory.

Answer (score 5):

I edited this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270862/9266796) so it also works for branches that contain slashes in their name, using `@` instead of `/` as a `sed` separator. Getting the branch name is also simpler now with `git branch --show-current`. I also moved the branch name to the bottom of the commit message since it makes more sense that the actual title of the message is what you see first.

The file should still be called `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`.

```
#!/bin/bash

branchName=$(git branch --show-current)
firstLine=$(head -n1 $1)

if [ -z "$firstLine"  ] ;then #Check that this is not an amend by checking that the first line is empty
    sed -i "1s@^@\n\n$branchName@" $1 #Insert branch name at the end of the commit message file
fi
```

Comment: side note: for Mac users, remember to add an empty string as a backup file extension, i.e., `sed -i "" "1s@^@\n\n$branchName@" $1`

Answer (score 3):

I adapted this for my needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

# hook arguments
COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
SHA1=$3

BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch --show-current)

# check branch name isn’t empty (typical e.g. during rebase)
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ]
then
  # check that this is a regular commit
  if [ "$COMMIT_SOURCE" = "message" ] || [ -z "$COMMIT_SOURCE" ]
  then
      sed -r -i "1!b;/^(fixup|squash)/! s@^@$BRANCH_NAME @" $COMMIT_MSG_FILE # insert branch name at the start of the commit message file
  fi
fi
```

Copy this snipped in a file called `prepare-commit-msg` inside your repos `.git/hooks` folder.

This should add the branch name in the case of `git commit`, `git commit -m …` and do nothing in case of merge, rebase etc.

Comment: Did the job for me (for my needs then with some modifications), but I did not know where to put this, found that it is in .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg, you may update your answer with this ;)

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues getting these solutions to work on MacOS due to the fact that it uses BSD `sed` instead of GNU `sed`. I managed to create a simple script that does the job though. Still using `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
BRANCH=$(cat .git/HEAD  | cut -d '_' -f2)
if [ ! -z "$BRANCH" ]
then
    echo "$BRANCH" > "/Users/username/.gitmessage" 
else
    echo "[JIRA NUMBER]" > "/Users/username/.gitmessage"
fi
```

This assumes a branch naming standard similar to `functional-desc_JIRA-NUMBER`. If your branch name is only your Jira ticket number you can simply get rid of everything from the pipe to the f2. It also requires that you have a file named `.gitmessage` in your home directory.

Comment: People using gitflow will have a branch that looks like "feature/ABC-123_some_description".

Answer (score 2):

You can use git prepare-commit-msg hook for this.

Hook can look like this:

```
# Get the currently checked-out branch name
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')

# Get the commit message, removing lines that start with a #
MESSAGE=$(cat "$1" | sed '/^#.*/d')

# Check if the commit message is non-empty
if [ -n "$MESSAGE" ]
then
    # Add the branch name and the commit message
    echo "$BRANCH_NAME: $MESSAGE" > "$1"
else
    echo "Aborting commit due to empty commit message."
    exit 1
fi
```

You probably don't want to include the branch name when committing merges, as default merge comment already includes branch names. When git does merge - it adds MERGE_HEAD file into the .git folder. So we can use that to exit hook before prepending branch name.

```
# Check if the MERGE_HEAD file is present
if [ -f ".git/MERGE_HEAD" ]
then
    exit 0
fi
```

Full hook can be fetched from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/wolf6101/f1857a41f5898328b7e5eef2686974b9#file-prepare-commit-msg).

Git hooks work per repository, so you will need to copy the hook file into the .git/hooks directory of each repository you want to use it in.
To automate the process of adding the git hook to multiple repositories, you can run next [script](https://gist.github.com/wolf6101/a90126e4b47a943e0235861516236eb3#file-apply-git-hooks-sh) in the root folder of your repositories.

You can fetch the script from gist to the root folder like this:

```
curl -s "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wolf6101/a90126e4b47a943e0235861516236eb3/raw/2f505db26d8adbabab9b93a8bb990ab42b2fb55c/apply-git-hooks.sh" -o "apply-git-hooks.sh"
```

To add hook:

```
sh apply-git-hooks.sh
```

To remove hook:

```
sh apply-git-hooks.sh remove
```

So now when you commit to the branch with the name ABC-123, like this:

```
git commit -m "I wrote something incredible, check this out"
```

You will get "ABC-123: I wrote something incredible, check this out"

This will work for commits via GUI as well.

Answer (score 1):

Piecing together the excellent answers here, and adding a few tweaks, my `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` script takes a branch name such as `feature/ABC-#123-feature-title` and outputs `ABC #123:`

```bash
COMMIT_MSG=$1
REPLACE_DELIMETER=true
FIRST_LINE=$(head -n1 $COMMIT_MSG)

addBranchName() {
  BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') # get the branch name (e.g. `feature/ABC-#123-feature-title`)
  NAME=${BRANCH_NAME##*/} # get everything after the last slash (e.g. `ABC-#123-feature-title`)
  DELIMITER=$(echo $NAME | grep -o '[-_]' | head -n1) # get the character that separates the parts (e.g. `-`)
  FEATURE_ID=$(echo $NAME | cut -d $DELIMITER -f 1,2) # get the first two parts of the name, split by the delimeter found in the branch name (e.g. `ABC-#123`)

  if [ "$REPLACE_DELIMETER" = true ]; then
    FEATURE_ID=$(echo $FEATURE_ID | sed "s/$DELIMITER/ /g") # replace the delimiter if `REPLACE_DELIMETER` is set to true (e.g. `ABC #123`)
  fi

  echo "$FEATURE_ID: $(cat $COMMIT_MSG)" > $COMMIT_MSG # prepend the name and parse the existing commit message (for instance commented out commit details)
}

if [ -z "$FIRST_LINE" ]; then # check that this is not an amend by checking that the first line is empty
  addBranchName
fi
```

Comment: Just a quick note on that. Most tools that allow you to connect commit messages to another tool want the ticket id intact at the beginning, so if you ticket ID is ABC-123, you want to keep it intact in the commit message as ABC-123 <your message>

Answer (score 0):

my bash add branch name and version from VERSION file around commit text

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #вторая версия, умеет вытаскивать текст коммита сообщений вида:
    # "$BRANCH текст ($VERSION)"
    # "текст ($VERSION)"
    # "$BRANCH текст"
    # "текст"
    #долбанный баш, перед и после = нельзя ставить пробелы
    
    COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$(echo $1 | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f1)
    VERSION_FROM_FILE=$(head -n 1 version)
    
    COMMIT_MSG_TEXT=$(cat "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"  | sed -r 's/.*PPP-[0-9]{0,6} (.*) ?/\1/') #убираем имя ветки если оно есть
    COMMIT_MSG_TEXT=$(echo "$COMMIT_MSG_TEXT"  | sed -r 's/(.* )\(.*\)/\1/') #убираем версию если она есть
    
    COMMIT_MSG_TEXT=$(echo "$COMMIT_MSG_TEXT" | xargs) #это обычный trim
    echo "текст коммита $COMMIT_MSG_TEXT"
    
    if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then  #в этих ветках ничего не подставляем
     BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop test)
    fi
    
    BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
    BRANCH_NAME="${BRANCH_NAME##*/}" #что тут происходит хз, какое то комбо на фаталити
    
    echo -n "$BRANCH_NAME $COMMIT_MSG_TEXT ($VERSION_FROM_FILE)" > $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
```

create new task in gradle(kotlin) with automatic install pre-commit-msg hook

```
task<Copy>("installGitHook") {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Install Pre-commit linting hook"
    from("gradle/prepare-commit-msg")
    into(".git/hooks")
    // Kotlin does not support octal litterals
    fileMode = 7 * 64 + 7 * 8 + 7
}

tasks.named("assemble") { dependsOn("installGitHook") }
```