# Git grep branch name and reformat into commit message

Tags: git, bash, shell, branch

Hi I want to create a default message from branch name. I know we can use hook to do this but I get some problem with grep function.

For exmaple, if our branch name is "test-1234-my-first-feature', how can I convert it into "[test-1234]"?

I think this is pure shell script question, can some help?

we can get branch and by this [How to add Git's branch name to the commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894946/how-to-add-gits-branch-name-to-the-commit-message)

```
BRANCH=`git branch | grep '^\*' | cut -b3-`
FILE=`cat "$1"`
echo "$BRANCH $FILE" > "$1"
```

Comment: so you want to get the two first words on a slash-based string?

Comment: Is the question here how to get just those first two `-` delimited fields? Will the branch name always look like that? Will there always be two fields you care about or can there be more?

Comment: You're better off getting the branch name with plumbing: `BRANCH=$( git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this added to your `prepare-commit-msg` will do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# prepend a task number to a commit message automatically

# if amend, don't do anything
if ! [ -z $3 ] ;then
    exit
fi

branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD)
task_number=$(echo $branch | cut -d - -f1-2)

if [ -z $task_number ] ;then        # when task has not been retrieved from branch name, exit
    exit
fi

# enclose task number in square brackets
text=[${task_number}]

sed -i "1s/^/$text \n/" $1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code is working but sed doesn't work so that I am using `echo` instead. Another small question, If I have branch name like `Feature/test-1234-sadf`, how can I cut `Feature/` out? Thx

Comment: `how can I cut Feature/ out` - well asked, use `cut` command: `echo Feature/test-1234-sadf | cut -d / -f 2`

Comment: When I do `git commit`, it gives a 
`sed: 1: ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG": invalid command code .`