# How do I create a git hook to prepend commit messages with branch name?

Tags: git, bash

I read [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894946/how-to-add-gits-branch-name-to-the-commit-message) that provided a somewhat working `prepare-commit-msg`, I modified it a little:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Automatically adds branch name and branch description to every commit message.
#
# todo:
# * breaks merge commit message
# * breaks git commit --amend

NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
DESCRIPTION=$(git config branch."$NAME".description)

echo "[$NAME]"' '$(cat "$1") > "$1"
if [ -n "$DESCRIPTION" ]
then
   echo "" >> "$1"
   echo $DESCRIPTION >> "$1"
fi
```

Taking the "happy path" that is:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'Some commit message'
```

will work as expected, output:

```
some-modular-app git:test-commit-hooks ❯ log | grep 9406dfb
* 9406dfb - [test-commit-hooks] Make edit (2 hours ago) <mbigras>
```

How there are two cases that do not work, if you use:

1.

```
git commit
```

to enter vim then the newlines are deleted for some reason, which forces one to edit the message to put the comments on their own line, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

2.

```
git commit --amend
```

Will cause the same problem as 1. but also it prepends a second `[branch-name]`, also shown below
[image]

[image]

How could I modify the above script to address the problem use cases 1 and 2?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is hidden in [a comment in that same Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894946/how-to-add-gits-branch-name-to-the-commit-message#comment31820573_11524807).  See also http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/06/checking-current-branch-programatically.html as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1593487/1256452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this snippet in your hook:

```
NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') 
echo -n "$NAME"': '|cat - "$1" > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out "$1"
```