# Add substring of current branch name to commit message

Tags: git

I would like to have a script set up which prepends my commit message with a part of my branch name.

The part of my branch name I want is the project ticket number.

The format of the branch will be one of the following:

```
feature/ABC-123-my-cool-branch

ABC-123-my-cool-branch
```

In each case, the part I want to extract is `ABC-123`.

Then I want to be able to assign the script to an alias like `commit-with-ticket-number` so that I can type:

```
$ commit-with-ticket-number "My fantastic commit"
```

and the result of the commit message will be:

```
"ABC-123 My fantastic commit"
```

How can I write such a script that prepends text based on my branch name to my commit message?

Comment: So you want the first two words of the branch? How do you determine what part to retain from the branch name?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894979/240564 you can edit modify this script