# Auto-add branch name to commits in Github (desktop)

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

How can I automatically add the branch name that I am currently working on to my commits?

For the moment I have to write it down manually each time I commit something:

```
[v1.2-branch-name] I did something
[v1.2-branch-name] I did something else
[v1.2-otherbranch-name] I did something else that did not mess up my code
```

I currently use Github Desktop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Git's branch name to the commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894946/how-to-add-gits-branch-name-to-the-commit-message)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+branch+name+commit+message

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you don't want to use a hook here, a simple alias could do the trick :

```
git config alias.cm '!f() { git commit -m "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) $1"; }; f'
```

then, assuming your current branch is named `v1.2-branch-name` just

```
git cm "My marvelous message"
```

would in fact create a commit with the following message

```
v1.2-branch-name My marvelous message
```

Comment: This is great, but does it also work if I git commit using the desktop app?