# Sorta of pre-commit hook for adding annotated tags in git

Tags: git, githooks

Is there's any way to trigger hook on adding a specific tag?
The idea is to have a separate build branch and to allow adding some specific annotated tags only in that branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a tag, you need to do it in a [`post-commit` hook](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html), not a `pre-commit` one.
However, a post-commit hook doesn't take any parameter.

You can check what is your current branch (`git symbolic-ref HEAD` as shown in "[Including the current branch name in the commit template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091005/6309)") and apply a tag if you are in the right branch.