# How to use the remote branch name in merge commit messages?

Tags: git, branch

I renamed my local branches to shorter names which works fine except when doing a merge.

The commit message automatically created for merges uses my local shortened name.

```
Merge branch 'shortname' into this-branch
```

This name is only for my convenience, so I would like to use the remote branch name in the commit log *(so we don't have every developers branch abbreviations showing up in the commit logs)*.

Is there a way to configure git to do this?

Comment: There's no easy way because all Git is doing is using the supplied string from the command line here. You can, however, either edit the message manually, or write a `prepare-commit-msg` hook. Since such a hook is a program entirely of your own devising, you can make it do anything you want. See [the githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) for details on Git hooks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the idea of a local hook, you can:

- store the full branch name in the [branch description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853/6309)

  ```
    git branch --edit-description
  ```
- use that branch description in a prepare-commit-msg hook which [would edit the commit merge message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524807/6309).

That way, the process is automated and can retrieve the original name of the branch.

An alternative approach, which would use *no hooks*, would be to define the `git-commit-template` in a git merge wrapper script. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316350/6309).
Again, you could get the original name from the branch description, but this time inject it in the merge commit message template.

---

Note that, with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), you cannot edit the description *and* set the upstream branch at the same time.

See [commit dc44639](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc44639904c9a0899854c79c97c248f3d3cc2bdc), [commit 6b70930](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b7093064a8db318bb18272a064590d558998dbf), [commit 6d504d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d504d5b0f6cf5eff454fd070c05ca3f014fc8fa) (15 Jun 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7b2685e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b2685ef2d637de333765f5406d36799894c9a38), 25 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc44639904c9a0899854c79c97c248f3d3cc2bdc): don't mix `--edit-description`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> `git branch` accepts `--edit-description` in conjunction with other arguments. However, `--edit-description` is its own mode, similar to `--set-upstream-to`, which is also made mutually exclusive with other modes.
> Prevent `--edit-description` from being mixed with other modes.