# Prefixing commit message in vs code with branch name

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there away to make VS Code automatically prepend branch name in commit message textarea?

Like if I'm on branch 'ID-7345' and just updated e.g. React.js version, I need to write:

`ID-7345: updated React.js to version 16.0`

and I would like to omit writing branch name each time there, so wherever I access this page I will see `ID-7345:` pre-populated and cursor blinking after it.

Answer (score 11):

There is now a VS Code extension that does the job: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=srmeyers.git-prefix.
By default, a click on the extension button will put into your commit message this label: "***[YourBranchName]***".
Into the extension settings, there are 3 parameters if you want to fine tune the label (copy/paste from the extension page):

- gitPrefix.pattern: Regular expression pattern to match in the branch 
  name. Default matches entire branch name.
- gitPrefix.patternIgnoreCase: Ignore case in pattern. Default is
  false.
- gitPrefix.replacement: Regular expression replacement string to place
  into commit message. Default is "[$1] ".

Comment: Thanks, @Tik for saving a lot of my time.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to do on VS Code, use this https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg or git template.
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086896/including-the-current-branch-name-in-the-commit-template) also, can be helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.