# Add column names to csv using sed on Mac OSx?

Tags: macos, sed, prepend

I have a csv file like this:

```
0,0,1
1,1,0
```

Notice that it does NOT have column names with it.  Write the column names at the beginning?  I looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723157/how-to-insert-a-newline-in-front-of-a-pattern) but this doesn't work on my Mac OSx:  `sed '1s/^/<column names>\n&/g'`.  It just adds the column names, and an `n` appended to them.    How do I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prepend to a file one liner shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365/prepend-to-a-file-one-liner-shell)

Answer (score 4):

If you really just want to prepend a line to an existing file, `cat` is all you need:

```sh
echo 'ColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3' | cat - file.csv > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ file.csv
```

Or, more efficiently, but perhaps more obscurely, using a [group command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html):

```sh
{ echo 'ColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3'; cat file.csv; } > /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ file.csv
```

Note the need to write to a temp. file first, because the shell doesn't support reading from and writing back to the same file using simple output redirection with `>` (the output file is truncated *before* the command executes).

---

That said, [shellter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989929/45375) points to a more convenient solution, using `sed`'s `-i` option for (limited) in-place updating (if supported):

- OS X and BSD systems (assumes `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`):

  ```sh
  sed -i '' $'1i\\\nColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3\n' file.csv
  ```
- Linux (GNU `sed`):

  ```sh
  sed -i  '1iColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3' file.csv
  ```

<sup>`-i` for in-place updating is a nonstandard extension to the POSIX standard, and the way it is implemented carries risks, most notably the potential destruction of a symlink. The same applies to the `> /tmp/$$ && mv /tmp/$$ ...` approach above.</sup>

---

As for **why your approach didn't work**:

```sh
sed '1s/^/<column names>\n&/' # Fails on OS X: Sed doesn't support \n in the replacement
```

<sup>As an aside: using the `g` option for *global* matching makes no sense, since you're matching the beginning of the line (`^`), so there can only be *one* match by definition.</sup>

**OS X** uses **BSD Sed**, which **doesn't support control-character escape sequences in the replacement part of the `s` function call** (unlike *GNU* Sed, which does).

As in the solution above, you could work around the problem with an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`) in `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`:

```sh
sed $'1s/^/<column names>\\\n&/' file.csv
```

Note the extra `\\`, which is needed to `\`-escape the *literal* newline that the `\n` expands to by virtue of the ANSI C-quoted string. (Escaping is needed, because a literal newline normally terminates a function call.)

Alternatively use *literal* newlines in your Sed script - but note that `\`-escaping the newline is still needed:

```sh
sed '1s/^/<column names>\
&/' file.csv
```

The above is what the ANSI C-quoted string solution effectively expands to.

If you want to learn about all the differences between the more flexible GNU Sed and BSD Sed, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Any `sed` will honor the `i\` (insert) command.

Try

```
 sed '1i\
        ColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3

 ' csv.file
```

**output**

```
ColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3
0,0,1
1,1,0
```

Newer `sed`s don't required that you have the input on a following line, hence for some systems

```
sed '1i\ColHdr1,ColHdr2,ColHdr3

 ' csv.file
```

Because you can use the `i\` to insert multiple lines into a file, you have to signal the end of input with a blank line.

IHTH

Comment: Again, this doesn't quite work:  `: extra characters after \ at the end of i command`

Comment: remove any trailing white space after the '\' char. Good luck.

Comment: Nicely done; however, a _single_ trailing newline is enough (and not even needed here with _GNU_ Sed); if you truly wanted to insert _multiple_ lines with `i`, the interior newlines would have to be `\ `-escaped - the first _unescaped_ newline terminates `i`'s argument.