# Sed with variables and spaces

Tags: sed, sh

How would I use a variable -containing spaces- as values in sed? - I'm using `sh` (not `bash`) as terminal.

What I'm trying to do (insert `a b c` in the first line of the file):

```
TMP='a b c'
sed -e '1i'${TMP} tmp.txt
```

However this errors with the message

```
dynamic-config-manager-nginx.sh: -: not found
```

And in the files I only see the first `a` inserted. - It seems that `sed` is exiting too early. "forcing" quotes around the string like below also doesn't work, with `"` command not found
    sed -e '"1e'${TMP}'"' tmp.txt

So how do I make this work?

Comment: does `sed -e '1i'"${TMP}" tmp.txt` work?

Comment: also, what is your sed version, as far as I know, you need backslash and newline after `i` command for non-GNU versions.. see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands

Comment: you could also use `echo "$TMP" | cat - tmp.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the `-i` option, to edit inplace. This gets us here:

```
$ sed -i -e '1i'${TMP} tmp.txt
sed: can't read b: No such file or directory
sed: can't read c: No such file or directory
```

`${TMP}` will be expanded to multiple arguments to `sed`. We want it all in a single string though:

```
sed -i -e "1i${TMP}" tmp.txt
```

One more caveat: `tmp.txt` must contain at least one line. If you know that `tmp.txt` doesn't exist or is an empty file, maybe do something like `echo > tmp.txt` first (warning: this will overwrite the file if it contained something).

Comment: this assumes GNU sed, for both `-i` option as well as `i` command... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux and https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that. :

Answer (score 0):

Solution with awk:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMP="a b c"
exec 3<> tmp.txt && awk -v TEXT="$TMP" 'BEGIN {print TEXT}{print}' tmp.txt >&3
```

[solution from John Mee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621786/1090147)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` with commands read from a here-doc

```
ed tmp.txt <<END_ED_COMMANDS
1i
$TMP
.
w
q
END_ED_COMMANDS
```