# Adding header to a table in unix

Tags: shell, unix, terminal

I am trying to add a header to following file.txt file

```
20481   20481   2       1
20483   20483   1       2
20488   20488   2       2
20492   20492   1       2
20493   20493   1       1
20498   20498   2       1
```

I have tried using awk `'NR == 1 { $0 = "FID IID SEX LUNG_CANCER" }; 1' file.txt > hdr.txt`
But it actually replaced the first line which is not correct. Where i am doing wrong.

```
FID IID SEX LUNG_CANCER
20483   20483   1       2
20488   20488   2       2
20492   20492   1       2
20493   20493   1       1
20498   20498   2       1
20500   20500   2       2
```

Comment: In the `NR == 1` block, just `print` the header, no need to manipulate $0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell one liner to prepend to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365/shell-one-liner-to-prepend-to-a-file)